# Quais as principais funções para se criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R?

Tags: r

Quais são ***as principais funções*** para se criar um [exemplo mínimo reproduzível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) em R?

Mais especificamente gostaria que as respostas tratassem dos seguintes tópicos:

- Quais as funções para garantir que a base de dados do exemplo possa ser replicada?
- Quais as funções para garantir que os resultados de simulações sejam replicados?
- Quais as funções para obter as informações do sistema?
- Quais partes do código devem ser colocadas para garantir reprodutibilidade?
- Como garantir que o exemplo fornecido irá ser reproduzido corretamente em outras máquinas?

Outras funções e práticas de programação importantes que por acaso tenha esquecido de mencionar nos tópicos e ajudem na criação de um exemplo mínimo reproduzível também são bem vindas.

Comment: Acho que fazer várias perguntas numa só foge um pouco do escopo. Vc fez 6 perguntas numa só (contando o título).

Comment: @dvd Essa pergunta foi discutida [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6704/6036)

Comment: @DanielFalbel você não quer colocar uma resposta explicando como usar o pacote reprex?

Answer (score 7):

A base de uma boa pergunta reprodutível é que deve ser possível que o **seu problema¹ apareça como problema para aqueles que irão tentar entendê-lo e resolvê-lo**.

## Linhas gerais

Para que possamos reproduzir seu problema o seguinte passo-a-passo pode ser seguido:

1. Tente reproduzir seu problema em sua máquina antes de enviá-lo ao StackOverflow.
2. Forneça o código que produziu (e que deverá reproduzir no computador alheio) o comportamento que motiva a pergunta.
3. Forneça dados capazes de reproduzir o problema.
4. Forneça o resultado esperado pelo código fornecido em 1.

## 1. Como reproduzir meu problema?

Abra um novo script e um novo ambiente. Se você estiver utilizando o RStudio você pode iniciar um nova seção clicando em `Session` na barra superior e depois `New Session`. Caso esteja usando o `R` (Rgui, R pela linha de comando, etc), basta abrir o programa mais um vez.

Neste novo ambiente copie o script original e vá rodando linha por linha até que se depare com o problema novamente. Este método permite isolar o problema nos seus determinantes fundamentais. Caso você esteja trabalhando em um script de 200 linhas, mas o erro acontece na linha 53, não há motivo para compartilhar as 147 linhas que se seguem ao erro e provavelmente boa parte das primeiras 53 linhas também podem ser excluídas do código que será partilhado.

Uma vez identificada a origem do problema, forneça aquela linha de código e **apenas as demais linhas necessárias para reproduzir o problema**. Digamos que o erro foi encontrado em:

```
sum(x)
```

Neste caso é necessário que também saibamos o que é `x`, ou seja, forneça o(s) objeto(s) `x` **no estado em que eles entraram na chamada da função** (ver item 3).

## 2. Como compartilhar meu código?

A maneira mais adequada é copiando e colando o **texto do seu código**. Parece trivial, mas [essa não é a única forma de fornecer o código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/43953).

Caso esteja se deparando com um erro ou aviso, forneça a mensagem.

```
sum(x)
Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

## 3. Como fornecer dados?

Como comentado acima, seus dados devem ser fornecidos no estado em que estavam quando o erro ocorreu. Para isso quando se deparar com o erro, utilize a função  `dput` para fornecer seu objeto tal como ele se encontra.

```
dput(x)
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
```

A função `dput` permite que seu objeto seja recriado em outra máquina, mesmo que ele tenha sido obtido de uma base de dados ou arquivo ou outra forma. Caso seu objeto seja muito grande utilize `dput(head(objeto, 30))` ou alguma outra forma de limitar o tamanho do objeto.

Há aqueles que gostam de fornecer as linhas de código que criaram o objeto. Ocorre que entre iniciantes é muito comum alterar o objeto posteriormente e, portante, o estado do objeto na linha original e na linha que gerou o erro podem (eu diria devem) mudar. Por esta razão utilizar `dput` garante maior reprodutibilidade do código e deve ser preferido.

Este é o caso no exemplo de erro que estou utilizando aqui:

```
x <- 1:5
x <- c(x, '6')
sum(x)
Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Caso seu código precise de alguma simulação, utilize `set.seed(1)` (ou qualquer outro número) para garantir que os resultados serão o mesmo em sua máquina e na daqueles que pretendem auxiliá-lo.

## 4. Como compartilhar o resultado esperado?

Isto pode ser feito de muitas formas. É possível utilizar um link ou imagem que contém o resultado esperado (no caso de um gráfico, [como este exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103995/como-fazer-um-gr%C3%A1fico-de-bolhas-cada-uma-delas-preenchida-de-acordo-com-uma-pro)). Também é possível descrever com palavras o que espera, como [neste caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257812/como-criar-grupos-de-3-palavras-em-um-texto-de-tamanho-aleat%C3%B3rio/257934#257934).

**EDITADO**

Para obter as informações do sistema como versão do `R`, sistema operacional, etc, basta chamar a função `sessionInfo()` (sem argumentos mesmo) e depois colar o resultado na sua pergunta.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2
```

---

1: Problema aqui não precisa ser entendido como um erro, mas simplesmente como a motivação da pergunta

2: Esta resposta foi originalmente publicada para [esta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6700/43953). Em razão [deste debate](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6704/43953), ela está sendo republicada aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Como consta no link da pergunta, um exemplo mínimo reproduzível deve ter os seguintes conteúdos:

1. Um pequeno conjunto de dados;
2. O menor código possível que seja **executável** e que reproduza o erro no pequeno conjunto de dados mencionado;
3. As informações sobre a versão do `R` e do sistema em que está rodando o código, bem como dos pacotes utilizados;
4. Se for utilizar dados aleatórios, garantir que os resultados sejam os mesmos;

Nessa resposta vou elencar algumas das ***principais funções em `R`*** para cumprir essas tarefas.

Vale lembrar que os exemplos ***das páginas de ajuda das funções do `R`*** podem ser de grande valia para ter uma noção da estrutura de um exemplo mínimo reproduzível. Em geral, os códigos dos exemplos da ajuda do `R` satisfazem a esses requisitos.

#### Produzindo o conjunto de dados

Para usar seu próprio conjuto de dados, a função `dput()`, juntamente com `head()` pode ser bastante útil. Por exemplo o código abaixo fornece as 10 primeiras observações da base de dados `iris` já com a estrutura necessária para "remontar" a base de dados. Assim, para quem for tentar responder a sua pergunta, basta copiar e colar o código em `structure()`.

```r
dput(head(iris, 10))
#> structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 
#> 5, 4.4, 4.9), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 
#> 3.4, 2.9, 3.1), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 
#> 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
#> 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
#> 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"
#> ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", 
#> "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"), row.names = c(NA, 
#> 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Reproduzindo os dados:

```r
dados <- structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(
  5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6,
  5, 4.4, 4.9
), Sepal.Width = c(
  3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4,
  3.4, 2.9, 3.1
), Petal.Length = c(
  1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7,
  1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5
), Petal.Width = c(
  0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2,
  0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1
), Species = structure(c(
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), .Names = c(
  "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",
  "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"
), row.names = c(
  NA,
  10L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Uma solução menos ideal do que esta seria fornecer os dados em formato texto, como, por exemplo, no caso abaixo:

```r
texto <- "Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa"
```

Neste caso, o usuário que for responder sua pergunta pode remontar a base de dados utilizando a função `read.table()`:

```r
dados <- read.table(text=texto)
```

Outra forma de produzir um conjunto de dados é gerando **valores aleatórios**, por exemplo, com a função `rnorm()` (você também pode gerar de outras distribuições sem ser a normal, caso seja pertinente) ou com a função `sample()` para uma amostragem de valores de algum vetor. Um caso útil pode ser a função `letters()`, para gerar caracteres ou fatores. Neste caso, não esqueça de fornecer a `seed` para que o exemplo seja reproduzível.

Exemplo:

```r
set.seed(1) # garantir reproducibilidade
dados <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = sample(letters, 10))
dados
#>             x y
#> 1  -0.6264538 y
#> 2   0.1836433 f
#> 3  -0.8356286 p
#> 4   1.5952808 c
#> 5   0.3295078 z
#> 6  -0.8204684 i
#> 7   0.4874291 a
#> 8   0.7383247 h
#> 9   0.5757814 x
#> 10 -0.3053884 v
```

Outras funções interessantes neste caso são as funções do tipo `as`, como  `as.factor()`, `as.Date()` etc, para você converter os dados para o formato necessário.

#### Produzindo o código mínimo

Tente identificar a menor parte necessária do seu código que gere o erro ou a dúvida que você tem.  Antes de enviar o código, certifique-se de que você ***elencou os pacotes necessários*** para que ele seja reproduzível. Para isso, é bom testar o seu código após reiniciar a sessão do `R`, para ter certeza de que tudo o que é necessário está lá.

Exemplo:

```r
library(lattice) # a biblioteca utilizada
set.seed(1) # a seed
dados <- data.frame(x = as.character(rnorm(10)), y = sample(letters, 10)) # o conjunto de dados
densityplot(as.numeric(dados$x))
```

[image]

```r
as.numeric(dados$x)
#>  [1]  2  5  4 10  6  3  7  9  8  1
```

Este exemplo corresponderia a uma pergunta do tipo: *"Estou tentando fazer um gráfico de densidade com o `lattice` como no código acima, porque quando converto os dados para numeric eles viram 2, 5, 4 ... e não permanecem como os dados originais do `rnorm`?"*

#### Informações do sistema

Por fim, quando necessário, você pode fornecer as informações do seu sistema com `sessionInfo()`, que dá informações detalhadas da sua seção. No meu caso, essas informações foram:

```r
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lattice_0.20-15

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.0.1  tools_3.0.1
```

#### Pacote reprex

Para ajudar a criar o exemplo reproduzível  o [pacote reprex](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/index.html) pode ser bastante útil, inclusive os exemplos anteriores foram gerado nele. Este é um pacote feito especificamente para ajudar a criar e executar exemplos reproduzíveis (o nome reprex é a abreviação de **Re**producible **Ex**ample), já com formatação para sites como GitHub e StackOverflow.

Uma forma simples de criar um exemplo reproduzível com o pacote é copiar o código em `R` para sua área de transferência. Depois basta carregar o pacote com `library(reprex)` e rodar o comando `reprex(venue = "so")` que o código com os resultados comentados ***já formatados*** estarão disponíveis para ser colados na venue escolhida (nesse exemplo "so" é a venue stackoverflow). Todas as imagens geradas são colocadas no imgur e o link é gerado automaticamente para postagem, bastando colar o resultado.

O pacote tem outras funções bastante úteis. Por exemplo, você pode automaticamente incluir as informações do sistema com o argumento `si = TRUE` e também automaticamente formatar o seu código usando [o estilo sugerido pelo Hadley](http://style.tidyverse.org/) com o argumento `style = TRUE`. Para mais informações veja  [a página do pacote.](http://reprex.tidyverse.org/)