# Como fazer uma busca automatizada na Web of Science usando R?

Tags: r

Então, eu possuo várias *search strings* com as quais quero fazer buscas na *Web of Science* (essas *search strings* estão organizadas numa planilha do Excel, onde cada linha corresponde a uma *search string*); o meu objetivo é saber o número de artigos que as buscas para cada *search string* possuem. Alguém saberia algum comando ou pacote do R que faça isso?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow! Dê uma olhada em [como melhorar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r) para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Uma boa alternativa é o pacote [rvest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/blob/master/README.md)