# Como criar um data frame de um banco de dados com base na diferença de duas datas em uma coluna de uma outra variável categórica no software R

Tags: r, data, data.frame

Eu tenho o seguinte banco de dados como exemplo e o resultado que eu espero:

[image: Exemplo]

---

No caso os valores no novo dataframe referem-se aos dias, que é a diferença da última data de uma categoria em relação a primeira da mesma categoria.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow! Dê uma olhada em [como melhorar suas próximas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r).

Answer (score 4):

É possível fazer o que quer com a função R base `aggregate`.

```
Grupo <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
Data <- c("01/02/2017", "15/02/2017", "20/03/2017", "18/02/2017", "01/03/2017", "15/02/2017", "20/02/2017")
dados <- data.frame(Grupo, Data)

dados$Data <- as.Date(dados$Data, "%d/%m/%Y")

result <- aggregate(Data ~ Grupo, dados, function(d) d[length(d)] - d[1])
result
#  Grupo Data
#1     A  47 
#2     B  11 
#3     C   5
```

Comment: Uma dúvida, antes tem uma variável de número do processo, como ficaria nesse caso:

Comment: @FVasquez É melhor editar a pergunta com os novos dados. Ponha a saída de `dput(dados)` ou se o banco for muito grande de `dput(head(dados, 20))`, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma de fazer isto é usando o pacote dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

dados <- tribble(
  ~Grupo, ~Data,
  "A", "01/02/2017", 
  "A", "15/02/2017", 
  "A", "20/03/2017", 
  "B", "18/02/2017", 
  "B", "01/03/2017", 
  "C", "15/02/2017", 
  "C", "20/02/2017"
) %>%
  mutate(Data = as.Date(Data, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))

result <- dados %>%
  group_by(Grupo) %>%
  summarise(Data = as.integer(max(Data) - min(Data))) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```