# Como converter um app Shiny, consistindo em múltiplos arquivos, em um exemplo reprodutível que possa ser compartilhado em uma pergunta?

Tags: r, shiny

## Problema

Aqui no Stackoverflow em Português há [guias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e também [perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r) cujo tema são os exemplos reprodutíveis. Entretanto não há nada equivalente para o [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) o que pode dificultar a vida dos iniciantes e também implicar em uma menor qualidade das respostas ou desinteresse dos usuários mais experientes em responder a pergunta.

Gerar uma boa pergunta para o [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) de acordo com os padrões do site pode ser muito difícil uma vez que um exemplo mínimo do shiny deve incluir um arquivo server.R, ui.R e ainda necessitar de um global.R. Mesmo que seja usado o padrão de arquivo único, um app.R, ainda assim pode haver a necessidade de incluir os estilos em CSS e também templates em HTML. Assim minha pergunta geral seria como **gerar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável para o [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny)**?

## Sumário

Eu gostaria que na resposta fosse incluído:

- linhas gerais de uma boa pergunta.
- um exemplo reprodutível.
- funções e outros recursos do R que possam ser úteis.

Comment: Essa pergunta não deveria estar no meta?

Comment: Não. Ela é sobre uma dificuldade técnica como tornar uma aplicação em `shiny` reprodutível. Isso pode servir para o SOpt, mas também para submeter _issues_ a mantenedores de pacotes, etc.

Answer (score 10):

### Linhas gerais

As linhas gerais ou os princípios que guiarão a construção da pergunta são os mesmos elencados [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/824/43953), [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6700/43953) e no [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264168/43953) citado na pergunta. O que vai mudar no [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) é *como* implantar estes princípios.

Estes princípios podem ser resumidos assim:

1. Compartilhe os **dados utilizados** (ou ao menos um parte deles);
2. Compartilhe um **código mínimo** que reproduz o problema
3. Compartilhe o **resultado obtido** (mensagens de erro, avisos ou telas geradas);
4. Compartilhe qual seria o **resultado esperado** com o código compartilhado;
5. Compartilhe as **informações de sessão** (versão do [r](/questions/tagged/r), pacotes usados) com `sessionInfo()`.

Como os itens 1 e 5 são resolvidos da mesma maneira do que para o [r](/questions/tagged/r) em geral, o restante da resposta foca nos itens 2 a 4.

Digamos a pergunta fosse:

> Como permitir que o usuário escolha um conjunto de dados em um [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny)?

### Código mínimo

#### Passo 1: reproduzir o problema

Para que outras pessoas possam de ajudar, elas precisarão reproduzir o seu problema. Então comece um arquivo novo (`app.R`) e insira nele o código de seu [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny).

Nesta etapa caso haja um `global.R` nesse [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny), este será o primeiro conteúdo do novo script. Depois copie e cole os conteúdos de `ui.R` e `server.R` definindo as variáveis `ui` e `server`. Termine por chamar chamar a função `shinyApp(ui, server)` com os objetos recém criados.

A grande vantagem de apresentar sua aplicação em um único script é que ele facilita a vida de quem irá responder a pergunta, pois basta um <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> e <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> para ter a aplicação rodando e começar a trabalhar na solução dos problemas apresentados.

Assim acabaríamos com um conteúdo similar ao que segue em `app.R`.

```
# antigo global.R
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

gerar_valores <- function(x) {
  rnorm(x, 10, 2)
}

set.seed(123)

# antigo ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(
    6,
    sliderInput("n", "Quantidade de observações", 30, 100, 65),
    plotOutput("hist")
  ),
  column(
    6,
    selectInput("dados", "Selecione o conjunto de dados",
                choices = list(carro = mtcars, flores = iris)),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)

# antigo server.R
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    hist(gerar_valores(input$n))
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(input$dados)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Passo 2: Isole o problema

Na aplicação do script acima temos dois *inputs*  e dois *outputs*, mas o problema está relacionado apenas a um conjunto de *input/output*.

Fornecer todo o código da aplicação na pergunta, antes de ajudar irá atrapalhar. Isso ocorre porque quem for se debruçar sobre o problema terá um trabalho a mais (identificar de que parte do script vem o erro). Em alguns casos, isso pode fazer inclusive com que desista de ajudar.

Para isolar o problema basta **se livrar de todo o código que não tem relação com ele**. No exemplo acima isso quer dizer remover todo do código relacionado a criação dos histogramas tanto na `ui` quanto no `server`. Assim teríamos:

```
# antigo global.R
library(shiny)

# antigo ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("dados", "Selecione o conjunto de dados",
              choices = list(carro = mtcars, flores = iris)),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

# antigo server.R
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(input$dados)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Resultado obtido

Para compartilhar o resultado obtido com o código compartilhado há, pelo menos, 3 opções.

1. Descrever o comportamento indesejado encontrado;
2. Compartilhar um link para a aplicação com o problema. Dentre os serviços que podem hospedar seu [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) posso citar o [shinyapps.io](http://shinyapps.io) e o [now.sh](https://www.curso-r.com/blog/2018-03-05-shiny-now/).
3. Compartilhar uma *screenshot* da aplicação com o problema.

Independente do método que escolher, não esqueça de compartilhar mensagens de erro ou avisos tanto do console quanto da `ui` da aplicação.

No caso acima teríamos algo como:

> A lista de opções, no lugar de apresentar os nomes dos conjuntos de dados, apresenta uma série de nomes e números, conforme tela abaixo. Também recebo estes erros em meu console:
>
> > Warning in min(x) :
> >       nenhum argumento não faltante para min; retornando Inf
> >
> > Warning in max(x) :
> >       nenhum argumento não faltante para max; retornando -Inf
> >
> > Warning: Error in plot.window: valores finitos são necessários para 'ylim'
> >       [No stack trace available]
>
> [image: tela de erro]

### Resultado esperado

Para explicar o resultado que esperava vejo 3 opções:

1. Descrever com palavras o resultado esperado;
2. Compartilhar um link para um caso (outra aplicação ou página) que esteja servindo de inspiração;
3. Rodar o resultado desejado fora do [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) e compartilhá-lo.

No exemplo fictício, poderia ser algo como.

> Consigo o resultado que espero com o comando
>
> `plot(mtcars)`
>
> Por que ele não funciona dentro do [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny)?

### Outros materiais (HTML/CSS/JS)

Os mesmos princípios usados para o código [r](/questions/tagged/r) podem ser usados para as demais linguagens: compartilhe **somente o essencial** e se estiver **relacionado ao problema** compartilhado. Compartilhe cada um em um pedaço próprio de código dentro da pergunta. Algo como:

> Este é o [css](/questions/tagged/css) que estou usando:
>
> ```
> .resultado {
>   background-color: green;
> }
> ```