# R, Shiny e mapas: Como renderizar um mapa de acordo com a escolha no dropdown_menu?

Tags: maps, r, shiny

Estou trabalhando em um app Shiny e gostaria que o mapa fosse renderizado de acordo com a escolha do usuário em um dropdown. Tenho três mapas (m1, m2 e m3), o que preciso colocar na ui e no server?

Segue um trecho reproduzível:

```
    ## Options ##
options("scipen"=20)

## Pacotes ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(BETS)

## Maps ##

# States
map<-st_read("./Brasil/UFEBRASIL.shp", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

IST<-BETSget(
  c(15925, 15926, 15927, 15928, 15929,
    15930, 15931, 15932, 15933, 15934,
    15935, 15936, 15937, 15938, 15939,
    15940, 15941, 15942, 15943, 15944,
    15945, 15946, 15947, 15948, 15949,
    15950, 15951),
  data.frame = TRUE)

IST1<-BETSget(
  c(15861, 15862, 15863, 15864, 15865,
    15866, 15867, 15868, 15869, 15870,
    15871, 15872, 15873, 15874, 15875,
    15876, 15877, 15878, 15879, 15880,
    15881, 15882, 15883, 15884, 15885,
    15886, 15887),
  data.frame = TRUE)

IST2<-BETSget(
  c(15893, 15894, 15895, 15896, 15897,
    15898, 15899, 15900, 15901, 15902,
    15903, 15904, 15905, 15906, 15907,
    15908, 15909, 15910, 15911, 15912,
    15913, 15914, 15915, 15916, 15917,
    15918, 15919),
  data.frame = TRUE)

names(IST)<-States
names(IST1)<-States
names(IST2)<-States

IST<-lapply(IST, tail, 1)
INST1<-lapply(IST1, tail, 1)
IST2<-lapply(IST2, tail, 1)


Estados<-c("ACRE",
           "ALAGOAS",
           "AMAPÁ",
           "AMAZONAS",
           "BAHIA",
           "CEARÁ",
           "DISTRITO FEDERAL",
           "ESPIRITO SANTO",
           "GOIÁS",
           "MARANHÃO",
           "MATO GROSSO",
           "MATO GROSSO DO SUL",
           "MINAS GERAIS",
           "PARÁ",
           "PARAÍBA",
           "PARANÁ",
           "PERNAMBUCO",
           "PIAUÍ",
           "RIO DE JANEIRO",
           "RIO GRANDE DO NORTE",
           "RIO GRANDE DO SUL",
           "RONDÔNIA",
           "RORAIMA",
           "SANTA CATARINA",
           "SÃO PAULO",
           "SERGIPE",
           "TOCANTINS"
)

IST<-data.frame(States = States,
                I = c(IST$`ACRE`$value,
                      IST$`ALAGOAS`$value,
                      IST$`AMAPÁ`$value,
                      IST$`AMAZONAS`$value,
                      IST$`BAHIA`$value,
                      IST$`CEARÁ`$value,
                      IST$`DISTRITO FEDERAL`$value,
                      IST$`ESPIRITO SANTO`$value,
                      IST$`GOIÁS`$value,
                      IST$`MARANHÃO`$value,
                      IST$`MATO GROSSO`$value,
                      IST$`MATO GROSSO DO SUL`$value,
                      IST$`MINAS GERAIS`$value,
                      IST$`PARÁ`$value,
                      IST$`PARAÍBA`$value,
                      IST$`PARANÁ`$value,
                      IST$`PERNAMBUCO`$value,
                      IST$`PIAUÍ`$value,
                      IST$`RIO DE JANEIRO`$value,
                      IST$`RIO GRANDE DO NORTE`$value,
                      IST$`RIO GRANDE DO SUL`$value,
                      IST$`RONDÔNIA`$value,
                      IST$`RORAIMA`$value,
                      IST$`SANTA CATARINA`$value,
                      IST$`SÃO PAULO`$value,
                      IST$`SERGIPE`$value,
                      IST$`TOCANTINS`$value)
)

IST1<-data.frame(States = States,
                 I = c(IST1$`ACRE`$value,
                       IST1$`ALAGOAS`$value,
                       IST1$`AMAPÁ`$value,
                       IST1$`AMAZONAS`$value,
                       IST1$`BAHIA`$value,
                       IST1$`CEARÁ`$value,
                       IST1$`DISTRITO FEDERAL`$value,
                       IST1$`ESPIRITO SANTO`$value,
                       IST1$`GOIÁS`$value,
                       IST1$`MARANHÃO`$value,
                       IST1$`MATO GROSSO`$value,
                       IST1$`MATO GROSSO DO SUL`$value,
                       IST1$`MINAS GERAIS`$value,
                       IST1$`PARÁ`$value,
                       IST1$`PARAÍBA`$value,
                       IST1$`PARANÁ`$value,
                       IST1$`PERNAMBUCO`$value,
                       IST1$`PIAUÍ`$value,
                       IST1$`RIO DE JANEIRO`$value,
                       IST1$`RIO GRANDE DO NORTE`$value,
                       IST1$`RIO GRANDE DO SUL`$value,
                       IST1$`RONDÔNIA`$value,
                       IST1$`RORAIMA`$value,
                       IST1$`SANTA CATARINA`$value,
                       IST1$`SÃO PAULO`$value,
                       IST1$`SERGIPE`$value,
                       IST1$`TOCANTINS`$value)
)

IST2<-data.frame(States = States,
                 I = c(IST2$`ACRE`$value,
                       IST2$`ALAGOAS`$value,
                       IST2$`AMAPÁ`$value,
                       IST2$`AMAZONAS`$value,
                       IST2$`BAHIA`$value,
                       IST2$`CEARÁ`$value,
                       IST2$`DISTRITO FEDERAL`$value,
                       IST2$`ESPIRITO SANTO`$value,
                       IST2$`GOIÁS`$value,
                       IST2$`MARANHÃO`$value,
                       IST2$`MATO GROSSO`$value,
                       IST2$`MATO GROSSO DO SUL`$value,
                       IST2$`MINAS GERAIS`$value,
                       IST2$`PARÁ`$value,
                       IST2$`PARAÍBA`$value,
                       IST2$`PARANÁ`$value,
                       IST2$`PERNAMBUCO`$value,
                       IST2$`PIAUÍ`$value,
                       IST2$`RIO DE JANEIRO`$value,
                       IST2$`RIO GRANDE DO NORTE`$value,
                       IST2$`RIO GRANDE DO SUL`$value,
                       IST2$`RONDÔNIA`$value,
                       IST2$`RORAIMA`$value,
                       IST2$`SANTA CATARINA`$value,
                       IST2$`SÃO PAULO`$value,
                       IST2$`SERGIPE`$value,
                       IST2$`TOCANTINS`$value)
)

Boxm1<-
  boxPlus(
    title = tags$b("States", style = 'font-family: "Georgia"'),
    closable = FALSE, 
    width = 6,
    status = "danger", 
    solidHeader = TRUE, 
    collapsible = TRUE,
    enable_dropdown = TRUE,
    dropdown_menu = dropdownItemList(), # What should i do here?
    leafletOutput("m1"), # What should i do here?
    footer = NULL
  )

## User Interface ##

header <- dashboardHeaderPlus(title = "MONITOR",
                              titleWidth = 200
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 150,
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Maps", tabName = "maps", icon = icon("globe-americas", lib = "font-awesome"))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    # Maps
    tabItem(tabName = "maps",
            fluidRow(
              Boxm1 # Maps
            )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$m1<-renderLeaflet({
    tmap_mode("view")
    IST<-inner_join(map, IST, by = c("NM_ESTADO" = "States"))
    IST<-IST[, c(3,1,2,4,5,6)]
    m1<-tm_shape(IST, name = "Maps") +
      tm_polygons("I", palette = "Reds", title = "")
    tmap_leaflet(m1)
  })

  output$m2<-renderLeaflet({
    tmap_mode("view")
    IST1<-inner_join(map, IST1, by = c("NM_ESTADO" = "States"))
    IST1<-IST1[, c(3,1,2,4,5,6)]
    m2<-tm_shape(IST1, name = "Maps") +
      tm_polygons("I", palette = "Reds", title = "")
    tmap_leaflet(m2)
  })

  output$m3<-renderLeaflet({
    tmap_mode("view")
    IST2<-inner_join(map, IST2, by = c("NM_ESTADO" = "States"))
    IST2<-IST2[, c(3,1,2,4,5,6)]
    m3<-tm_shape(IST2, name = "Maps") +
      tm_polygons("I", palette = "Reds", title = "")
    tmap_leaflet(m3)
  })

}


## App ##
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: basta colocar os `leafletOutput()` dentro do `body`. Tem que usar os mesmos `id`s que foram usados no server.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SOpt! Veja algumas dicas de como melhorar sua pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297036/como-converter-um-app-shiny-consistindo-em-m%C3%BAltiplos-arquivos-em-um-exemplo-re)

Answer (score 1):

**INTRODUÇÃO**

Inicialmente eu gostaria de salientar que pelo código do seu app e pelos problemas que existiam nele eu creio que provavelmente você está começando a utilizar o `Shiny`. Eu vou então apresentar a solução para o seu problema e em seguida comentar os erros que você cometeu no design da sua aplicação Shiny.

Caso quem estiver lendo não queria copiar e colar código, todo o código fonte incluindo os dados estão neste [repositório](https://github.com/flaviobarros/SOpt-shiny-mapas/tree/master) do Github.

**SOLUÇÃO**

Para fazer o seu app funcionar eu tive que fazer várias coisas:

1. separar a preparação de dados do app em si;
2. armazenar os dados pré-processados em uma pasta dados;
3. alterar a sua interface;

Alterando a sua estrutura de diretórios para incluir os dados e separar a preparação do app em si, ficou assim:

```
├── app.R
├── Brasil
│   ├── UFEBRASIL.dbf
│   ├── UFEBRASIL.prj
│   ├── UFEBRASIL.sbn
│   ├── UFEBRASIL.sbx
│   ├── UFEBRASIL.shp
│   └── UFEBRASIL.shx
├── data
│   ├── IST1.rda
│   ├── IST2.rda
│   ├── IST.rda
│   └── map.rda
├── preparation.R
└── shiny-maps.Rproj
```

Aqui é importante salientar que há dois arquivos em `R`: o `preparation.R` e o `app.R`. **Mas porque separar?** Aqui é importante salientar que muitas vezes, quando estamos fazendo uma análise na nossa máquina, trabalhamos no console de forma iterativa, incluindo o uso de funções que demoram vários minutos para terminar. Em um app `Shiny` seu usuário não precisa e não **vai** esperar vários minutos para ver a informação que ele quer. **Por isso** é **super importante** que as partes mais computacionalmente custosas do seu app já estejam pré-processadas e aí você só carrega os dados prontos para uso no seu app. Nesse caso em específico, no arquivo `preparation.R` são criados os arquivos de dados `IST1.rda`, `IST2.rda` e `IST.rda`, salvos na pasta `data`.

Os códigos do arquivo `app.R` ficaram assim:

```
## Options ##
options("scipen"=20)

## Pacotes ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tmap)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

## Loadind data ##
load(file = 'data/map.rda')
load(file = 'data/IST.rda')
load(file = 'data/IST1.rda')
load(file = 'data/IST2.rda')

## User Interface ##
## Cabeçalho
header <- dashboardHeaderPlus(title = "MONITOR",
                              titleWidth = 200
)

## Barra lateral
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 150,
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Mapa1", tabName = "mapa1"),
    menuItem("Mapa2", tabName = "mapa2"),
    menuItem("Mapa2", tabName = "mapa3")
  )
)

## Caixa 1 para o mapa 1
Boxm1 <-
  boxPlus(
    title = tags$b("States", style = 'font-family: "Georgia"'),
    closable = FALSE, 
    width = 6,
    status = "danger", 
    solidHeader = TRUE, 
    collapsible = TRUE,
    enable_dropdown = TRUE,
    leafletOutput("m1"), # What should i do here?
    footer = NULL
  )

## Caixa 2 para o mapa 2
Boxm2 <-
  boxPlus(
    title = tags$b("States", style = 'font-family: "Georgia"'),
    closable = FALSE, 
    width = 6,
    status = "danger", 
    solidHeader = TRUE, 
    collapsible = TRUE,
    enable_dropdown = TRUE,
    leafletOutput("m2"), # What should i do here?
    footer = NULL
  )

## Caixa 3 para o mapa 3
Boxm3 <-
  boxPlus(
    title = tags$b("States", style = 'font-family: "Georgia"'),
    closable = FALSE, 
    width = 6,
    status = "danger", 
    solidHeader = TRUE, 
    collapsible = TRUE,
    enable_dropdown = TRUE,
    leafletOutput("m3"), # What should i do here?
    footer = NULL
  )

## Body do dashboard
body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    # Maps
    tabItem(tabName = "mapa1",
            fluidRow(
              Boxm1 # Maps
            )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "mapa2",
            fluidRow(
              Boxm2 # Maps
            )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "mapa3",
            fluidRow(
              Boxm3 # Maps
            )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(header, sidebar, body)

## Server ##
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$m1 <- renderLeaflet({
    tmap_mode("view")
    IST <- inner_join(map, IST, by = c("NM_ESTADO" = "State"))
    IST <- IST[, c('NM_ESTADO', 'value', 'geometry')]
    m1  <- tm_shape(IST, name = "Maps") +
      tm_polygons(col = "value", palette = "Reds", title = "")
    tmap_leaflet(m1)
  })

  output$m2 <- renderLeaflet({
    tmap_mode("view")
    IST1 <- inner_join(map, IST1, by = c("NM_ESTADO" = "State"))
    IST1 <- IST1[, c('NM_ESTADO', 'value', 'geometry')]
    m2  <- tm_shape(IST1, name = "Maps") +
      tm_polygons(col = "value", palette = "Blues", title = "")
    tmap_leaflet(m2)
  })

  output$m3 <- renderLeaflet({
    tmap_mode("view")
    IST2 <- inner_join(map, IST2, by = c("NM_ESTADO" = "State"))
    IST2 <- IST2[, c('NM_ESTADO', 'value', 'geometry')]
    m3  <- tm_shape(IST2, name = "Maps") +
      tm_polygons(col = "value", palette = "Oranges", title = "")
    tmap_leaflet(m3)
  })
}

## App ##
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

veja que este é o seu app e que logo no início eu carrego os `data.frames` já pré-processados *offline* para utilizar no app. Veja também que eu organizei os seus mapas em `tabItems`, um para cada mapa, tal que ao clicar em um tab você mostra um mapa diferente. Também troquei a cor dos mapas para mostrar que cada um é um mapa diferente.

O seu arquivo `preparation.R` ficou assim:

```
## Packages
library(BETS)
library(purrr)
library(sf)

## Maps ##
# States
map <- st_read("Brasil/UFEBRASIL.shp", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Baixando as séries
IST <- BETSget(
  c(15925, 15926, 15927, 15928, 15929,
    15930, 15931, 15932, 15933, 15934,
    15935, 15936, 15937, 15938, 15939,
    15940, 15941, 15942, 15943, 15944,
    15945, 15946, 15947, 15948, 15949,
    15950, 15951),
  data.frame = TRUE)

IST1 <- BETSget(
  c(15861, 15862, 15863, 15864, 15865,
    15866, 15867, 15868, 15869, 15870,
    15871, 15872, 15873, 15874, 15875,
    15876, 15877, 15878, 15879, 15880,
    15881, 15882, 15883, 15884, 15885,
    15886, 15887),
  data.frame = TRUE)

IST2 <- BETSget(
  c(15893, 15894, 15895, 15896, 15897,
    15898, 15899, 15900, 15901, 15902,
    15903, 15904, 15905, 15906, 15907,
    15908, 15909, 15910, 15911, 15912,
    15913, 15914, 15915, 15916, 15917,
    15918, 15919),
  data.frame = TRUE)

## Retirando a última observação e transformando em data.frame
IST  <- map_df(.x = IST,  .f = function(x) x[nrow(x),])
IST1 <- map_df(.x = IST1, .f = function(x) x[nrow(x),])
IST2 <- map_df(.x = IST2, .f = function(x) x[nrow(x),])

## Definindo os nomes da variável para o estado
IST$State <- map$NM_ESTADO
IST1$State <- map$NM_ESTADO
IST2$State <- map$NM_ESTADO

## Retendo somente estados e os valores
IST  <- IST[,c(3,2)]
IST1 <- IST1[,c(3,2)]
IST2 <- IST2[,c(3,2)]

## Salvando os data.frames para uso posterior
save(map, file = 'data/map.rda')
save(IST, file = 'data/IST.rda')
save(IST1, file = 'data/IST1.rda')
save(IST2, file = 'data/IST2.rda')
```

E por fim esse é o comportamento do seu app:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBSERVAÇÕES**

Eu creio que é possível deixar o app ainda melhor e mais otimizado. Como eu não sei exatamente quais são os seus objetivos com essa aplicação eu me limitei a fazer exatamente o que estava na pergunta.