# Como criar um ótimo exemplo reprodutível em R?

Tags: r

Eu já fiz uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297036/como-converter-um-app-shiny-consistindo-em-m%C3%BAltiplos-arquivos-em-um-exemplo-re) anteriormente sobre como produzir exemplos reprodutíveis para perguntas envolvendo o [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny). Aqui no Stackoverflow em Português há [guias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e também [perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r) cujo tema são os exemplos reprodutíveis. Entretanto não há nada especificamente para o [r](/questions/tagged/r) que forneça informações sobre o tópico de forma abrangente o que pode dificultar a vida dos iniciantes e também implicar em uma menor qualidade das respostas ou desinteresse dos usuários mais experientes em responder a pergunta.

Quais são as suas dicas para criar um excelente exemplo reprodutível? Como apresentar as estruturas de dados? Quais informações complementares devem estar incluídas na pergunta? Enfim, como criar um ótimo exemplo reprodutível em R?

OBS: estou ciente da pergunta [Quais as principais funções para se criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r) mas meu intuito aqui é mais geral e o objetivo é ser um guia para aqueles usuários que são solicitados produzir uma pergunta reprodutível.

Comment: Hoje em dia a máxima é: copie seu código (ctrl + c) e manda um `reprex::reprex()`. Ai cola o resultado aqui.

Comment: Na verdade eu procuro algo mais elaborado que isso. Uma pergunta similar é uma das mais votadas no stackoverflow em inglês com múltiplas respostas ;-)

Comment: Entendo. A formulação da pergunta que indicas na observação tem o mesmo objetivo. A forma como foi elaborada (pedindo funções) foi para que a comunidade com um todo aceitasse ela aqui no site principal.

Comment: Veja o destino dessas perguntas: [primeira](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r), [segunda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r)

Comment: @TomásBarcellos no meu entender foi um equívoco retirar justamente as perguntas que iam diretamente ao foco. Nos indexadores é mais provável que alguém procure um exemplo reprodutível que simplesmente funções. Talvez a solução fosse alterar o texto da pergunta pelo menos.

Comment: Eu concordo com você e lutei para que isso não acontecesse. Ocorre que perdi :(