# Error in scan (file=file, what=what...)

Tags: r

Bom Dia, estou com um erro para rodar um código no meu R.

**Segue abaixo o código.**

```
library(car)
library(fBasics)
library(NbClust)

setwd("C:/Financas") # Salvar na pasta
Base = read.table("baseFin.txt", header=TRUE) #Importa o arquivo

head(Base)
tail(Base)

papel       = Base$Papel
evebit      = Base$EVEBIT
cresrec     = Base$CresRec
lpa         = Base$LPA
vpa         = Base$VPA
margliq     = Base$MargLiquida
ebitativo   = Base$EBITAtivo
liqucorr    = Base$LiquCorr
divbrpatr   = Base$DivBrPatrim
```

O objetivo principal desses códigos é pegar na base de dados os indicadores e fazer o que está escrito no código.

**Essa é a base de dados**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Esse é o erro que aparece no meu R**

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  
: 
linha 1 não tinha 14 elementos
```

Comment: Na sua primeira linha, que você indica como um `header = TRUE`, há espaço entre as palavras do título de uma mesma coluna. Tenta colocar um caracter como `_` entre as palavras.

Comment: @MatheusTostes, evite compartilhar informações como imagem. Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264168/43953) sobre como melhorar suas próximas perguntas.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o seu cabeçalho tem nomes de colunas com espaços. Você tem algumas opções.

Muda o arquivo. A melhor, Mas nem sempre possível.

Ignora o cabeçalho. E coloca os nomes.

```
Base = read.table("baseFin.txt", skip = 1, col.names = c("col1", "col2", "col3") # se vira com os nomes porque o seu arquivo é uma imagem.
```

Se o seu arquivo for separado por tabulação, você pode usar os nomes das colunas como estão. Mas não faz isso não, por favor.

```
 Base = read.csv2("baseFin.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
```