# Exemplo de utilidade do Tidytext

Tags: r, analise-de-texto

Hj em uma palestra da minha universidade eu vi um pacote q é chamado de Tidytext...entendi como ele funciona, so q nao consigo pensar em nenhuma utilidade dele.Alguem poderia me dar um exemplo d como tirariamos proveito  dele em problemas do dia a dia?
Obrigado!

Comment: [Este link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/vignettes/tidytext.html), disponibilizado pelos próprios criadores do pacote, dá uma ideia do que ele é capaz de fazer.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em português, @GabrielOliveiraGuimarães. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r) você pode encontrar algumas dicas sobre como melhorar suas próximas perguntas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O  `tidytext` é um pacote que busca instrumentalizar análises de textos de um modo geral e, portanto, possui 1001 utilidades (e as mais importantes delas podem ser encontradas na vinheta princiapal do pacote, como apontado pelo @MacusNunes). Dentre algumas das possibilidades que existem na analise de texto que estão implantadas no `tidytext` eu destacaria:

1. Freqüência dos termos
2. Matriz termo-documento (tdm, inglês)
3. Frequência dos termos - inverso da frequência nos documentos (tf-idf, inglês)
4. Análise de sentimentos

### Exemplo de utilidade - Frequência das palavras

#### Passo 1 -  Pegar um texto qualquer para análise

```
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("tomasbarcellos/valorrr")

library(valorrr)
sessao <- html_session("http://www.valor.com.br/")
links <- links_pagina(sessao)
# Primeiras 20 notícias
noticias <- ler_noticia(sessao, links[1:20])
```

Agora já temos o texto das 20 primeiras notícias de agora do jornal Valor Econômico.

#### Passo 2 - Usar o tidytext para analisar os textos

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

noticias_tidy <- noticias %>% 
  select(titulo, texto) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, texto)

stop_port <- get_stopwords(language = "pt")

noticias_tidy %>% 
  anti_join(stop_port) %>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE)

Joining, by = "word"
# A tibble: 2,069 x 2
   word              n
   <chr>         <int>
 1 r                55
 2 é                52
 3 bilhões          44
 4 governo          37
 5 caminhoneiros    28
 6 paulo            27
 7 ônibus           26
 8 diesel           24
 9 petrobras        24
10 presidente       23
# ... with 2,059 more rows
```

Sem ler nenhuma das notícias já podemos perceber que o jornal está hoje focado em matérias sobre a greve dos caminhoneiros e na política de combustíveis.

> Observação: As palavras `r` e `é` aparecem porque não fizemos nenhuma limpeza nos dados para tornar este exemplo mais simples.

O uso de `bigramas` torna esta conclusão ainda mais obvia:

```
regex_stop <- paste0("\\b", stop_port$word, "\\b", collapse = "|")

noticias_bigram <- noticias %>% 
  select(titulo, texto) %>% 
  mutate(texto = str_remove_all(texto, regex_stop)) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, texto, "ngrams", n = 2)

noticias_bigram %>% count(word, sort = TRUE)

# A tibble: 4,365 x 2
   word                    n
   <chr>               <int>
 1 são paulo              26
 2 quinta feira           13
 3 pis cofins             10
 4 greve caminhoneiros     8
 5 preço diesel            8
 6 15 dias                 7
 7 desta quinta            7
 8 nesta quinta            7
 9 além disso              6
10 capital paulista        6
# ... with 4,355 more rows
```

#### Passo 3 - Escolha seu próximo objetivo

Uma vez que tenhamos um texto estruturado no formato `tidy`, o céu é o limite. Daqui poderíamos, por exemplo, criar matrizes de termo-documento que alimentariam um modelo de predição do autor do texto; ou visualizar o uso das palavras numa nuvem de palavras, etc.