# Incluir coluna em um select

Tags: sql, r

Em meu trabalho, sempre extraio do sql, tabelas, numa dessas tabelas a informação extraida é contratos, data, qtde de discagem, qtde de atendido, qtde de alo, e por assim vai.
Ressalto que utilizo Rstudio, com uma conexão via odbc para extrair a base.
A pergunta é como incluo uma coluna nesse select ai, sendo que necessito de uma coluna de telefones.
Esssa é o codigo

```
sql_server_temp  <- sqlQuery(channel = conn, query =

                              paste0("SELECT x.Contrato, x.data_registro, x.cart, SUM(x.Discado) AS disc_esf, SUM(x.Atendido) AS atend_esf, SUM(x.alo) AS alo_esf, SUM(x.cpc) AS cpc_esf,  ",

                                     "SUM(x.Discado_unique) AS disc_uni, SUM(x.Atendido_unique) AS atend_uni, SUM(x.alo_unique) AS alo_uni, SUM(x.cpc_unique) AS cpc_uni  ",

                                     "FROM (SELECT Data_Registro, 'ADM' AS cart, CAST(Contrato AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Contrato,SUM(CASE WHEN Discado = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Discado,  ",

                                     "SUM(CASE WHEN Atendido = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Atendido, SUM(CASE WHEN alo = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS alo,   ",

                                     "SUM(CASE WHEN cpc = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cpc, CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Discado = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Discado_unique,  ",

                                     "CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Atendido = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Atendido_unique, CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN alo = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS alo_unique,   ",

                                     "CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN cpc = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cpc_unique FROM Vw_Acionamento  ",

                                     "WHERE tipo_discagem = 'OUTBOUND' AND Cod_Carteira IN (98) AND Data_Registro BETWEEN '",data_ini,"' AND '",data_fini,"' ",

                                     "GROUP BY Data_Registro, CAST(Contrato AS VARCHAR(100))) AS x GROUP BY x.Contrato,x.Data_Registro, x.cart"))
```

Como já dito, existe a possibilidade de incluir uma coluna ai, me ajudem.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow! Não ficou claro o que você quer dizer com incluir coluna. Como o resultado que você obtém difere do desejado? Dê uma olhada em [como melhorar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ronaldo, tudo bem?

A estrutura da sua query é mais ou menos esta:

```
<- sqlQuery(channel = conn, query = 
              paste0("SELECT x.coluna1, x.coluna2, sum(x.col3) AS coluna3 ",
                     "FROM (SELECT coluna1, coluna2, sum(col3) as coluna3 "
                     "GROUP BY coluna1, coluna2) GROUP BY x.coluna1, x.coluna2"))
```

Ou seja, você está fazendo um SELECT onde traz os campos coluna1, coluna2 e soma da coluna3 FROM outro SELECT que traz os campos coluna1, coluna2 e soma da coluna3. Como está fazendo uma somatória da coluna 3, tanto no primeiro como no segundo SELECT, faz-se necessário agrupar os campos coluna1 e coluna2, nas nos dois SELECTs. Por isso que tem o tal de GROUP BY aparecendo duas vezes.

Enfim, se você quer trazer o campo TELEFONE, você primeiro precisa incluir o campo TELEFONE no segundo SELECT e também incluí-lo na cláusula GROUP BY. Em seguida incluir o Telefone no primeiro SELECT, mas também não esquecer de incluí-lo na cláusula GROUP BY.

Exemplo:

```
<- sqlQuery(channel = conn, query = 
              paste0("SELECT x.coluna1, x.coluna2, sum(x.col3) AS coluna3, x.TELEFONE ",
                     "FROM (SELECT coluna1, coluna2, sum(col3) as coluna3, TELEFONE "
                     "GROUP BY coluna1, coluna2, TELEFONE) GROUP BY x.coluna1, x.coluna2, x.TELEFONE"))
```

Como não tenho o seu banco de dados, não pude fazer o teste, mas sua query irá ficar assim:

```
<- sqlQuery(channel = conn, query =

              paste0("SELECT x.Contrato, x.data_registro, x.cart, SUM(x.Discado) AS disc_esf, SUM(x.Atendido) AS atend_esf, SUM(x.alo) AS alo_esf, SUM(x.cpc) AS cpc_esf,  ",

                     "SUM(x.Discado_unique) AS disc_uni, SUM(x.Atendido_unique) AS atend_uni, SUM(x.alo_unique) AS alo_uni, SUM(x.cpc_unique) AS cpc_uni, x.TELEFONE  ",

                     "FROM (SELECT Data_Registro, 'ADM' AS cart, CAST(Contrato AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Contrato,SUM(CASE WHEN Discado = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Discado,  ",

                     "SUM(CASE WHEN Atendido = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Atendido, SUM(CASE WHEN alo = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS alo,   ",

                     "SUM(CASE WHEN cpc = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cpc, CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Discado = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Discado_unique,  ",

                     "CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Atendido = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Atendido_unique, CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN alo = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS alo_unique,   ",

                     "CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN cpc = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cpc_unique FROM Vw_Acionamento, TELEFONE  ",

                     "WHERE tipo_discagem = 'OUTBOUND' AND Cod_Carteira IN (98) AND Data_Registro BETWEEN '",data_ini,"' AND '",data_fini,"' ",

                     "GROUP BY Data_Registro, CAST(Contrato AS VARCHAR(100)), TELEFONE) AS x GROUP BY x.Contrato,x.Data_Registro, x.cart, x.TELEFONE"))
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, deu certo!