# O gráfico não aparece quando coloco o shiny pra rodar

Tags: r, shiny

Tenho esse código para um aplicativo shiny. Aparentemente não tem erro no código e quando seleciono apenas o gráfico consigo plotar, porém quando eu coloco pra rodar o gráfico não aparece .

```
cat(getwd())
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dados <- ipeadata_taxa_desemprego_05_06_2018_10_39_ 


ui <- fluidPage(


   titlePanel("Porcentagem de Pessoas Desempregadas por Estado"),

   fluidRow(
     selectInput("estado", label = ("Estado1"),
                 choices = list("NULL", "Acre" , "Alagoas", "Amapá", "Amazonas", "Bahia", "Ceará" , "Brasília" , "Espírito Santo", "Goiás",                   "Maranhão", "Mato Grosso do Sul" ,"Cuiabá", "Minas Gerais",                               "Pará", "Paraíba", "Paraná" , "Pernambuco", "Piauí",                                "Rio de Janeiro", "Rio Grande do Norte", "Rio Grande do Sul",                                "Rondônia", "Roraima", "São Paulo", "Santa Catarina",                                "Sergipe", "Tocantins"
                 ),selected = "Acre"
     )
   )
   )
   mainPanel(
     plotOutput("app")
   )


server <- function(input, output) {

     output$app <- renderPlot({

      dados_plot <- dados %>% 
        select(., -Sigla, -Código, -X9) %>%  ### tira as colunas que não vai precisar
        filter(Estado == "input$estado") %>%  ### seleciona o estado
        gather("Anos", "Valor", 2:6) %>%    ### transforma as colunas em linha
         mutate("Anos" = as.factor(Anos))   ### trnasforma num fator

      ggplot(dados_plot, aes(x = reorder(Anos,Valor), y = Valor, fill = Estado)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip() +
      labs(x = "Anos", y = "Porcentagem (%)", title = "Estado")
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em português. Você poderia nos informar qual a mensagem do erro que você recebe? E também copiar e colar o resultado de `dput(head(dados, 30))`? Veja estas e outras dicas [como melhorar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r).

Answer (score 1):

Para reproduzir os problema criei dados como segue:

```
dados <- data_frame(
  Estado =  c("Acre" , "Alagoas", "Amapá", "Amazonas", "Bahia", "Ceará"),
  Sigla = NA, Código = NA, X9 = NA, # código vai remover
  `1995` = abs(rnorm(6)) * 1000, `2000` = abs(rnorm(6)) * 1000, 
  `2005` = abs(rnorm(6)) * 1000, `2010` = abs(rnorm(6)) * 1000, 
  `2015` = abs(rnorm(6)) * 1000
)
```

Há alguns problemas no código fornecido na pergunta. Mas aquele que motiva a pergunta está na `ui`.

No código fornecido, o `mainPanel(...)` está depois de fechar a `fluidPage(...)` e por isso ele não está incluído na página (objeto `ui`).

Uma vez que o gráfico seja incluído, o código apresenta um problema no `server`. No `filter`, a coluna `Estado` está sendo comparada com o texto `"input$estado"` e não com o objeto `estado` da lista `input`. Para obter resultado desejado, basta remover as aspas ao redor do nome do objeto.

Por fim, o código que reproduz a solução é este:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Porcentagem de Pessoas Desempregadas por Estado"),

  fluidRow(
    selectInput("estado", label = ("Estado1"),
                choices = unique(dados$Estado),
                selected = "Acre"
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("app")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$app <- renderPlot({
    dados_plot <- dados %>% 
      select(., -Sigla, -Código, -X9) %>%  ### tira as colunas que não vai precisar
      filter(Estado == input$estado) %>%  ### seleciona o estado
      gather(Anos, Valor, 2:6) %>%    ### transforma as colunas em linha
      mutate(Anos = as.factor(Anos))   ### trnasforma num fator

    ggplot(dados_plot, aes(x = reorder(Anos, Valor), y = Valor, fill = Estado)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip() +
      labs(x = "Anos", y = "Porcentagem (%)", title = "Estado")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```