# Dúvidas sobre chamar vários objetos, um a um em iterações de um looping em R

Tags: r

Importei alguns objetos da seguinte maneira, nesse exemplo coloquei apenas dois, mas pretendo trabalhar com muitos, por isso preciso automatizar um pouco os processos:

```
library(quantmod)

#escolhendo a data que deseja
start <- as.Date("2014-01-01")
end<- as.Date("2018-01-12")

#primeiro termo refere a quais ativos vc quer baixar
#segundo de onde vc quer
#terceiro a data inicial
#quarto a data final
getSymbols(ativos, src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
```

Após a importação dos objetos, preciso trasnformá-los em `data.frame` e alterar os cabeçalhos deles, em um `for`, mas não estou conseguindo chamar cada objeto em cada iteração.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de um jeito de alterar todos os cabeçalhos em um `for`, assim como transformar todos em `data.frame` em um `for`, porém não consigo chamar cada objeto em cada iteração.

Tentei fazer assim mas não deu certo:

```
#cabeçalho dos ativos importados
cabecalho<-c("abertura","máxima", "mínima", "fechamento", "volume", "ajuste")

ativos2<-list(BVSP,PETR4.SA)


for(i in 1:NROW(ativos2)){

  colnames(ativos2[i])<-cabecalho

}
```

## Como sugerido pelo colega no comentário refiz esse for da seguinte maneira

```
for(i in 1:NROW(ativos2)){

 colnames(ativos2[[i]])<-cabecalho

}
```

## E aparece o seguinte erro

Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = cabecalho) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions

Comment: Na ultima linha, tente utilizar 2 colchetes ao invés de somente 1: `ativos2[[i]]`. Caso não dê certo, edite a pergunta e adicione a mensagem de erro. Você também pode fornecer mais informações descrevendo as `class()` dos objetos `BVSP`, `PETR4`.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow! Dê uma olhada em [como melhorar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r) para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Em especial, compartilhar o resultado de `dput(ativos2)` pode ajudar

Comment: Parece que o problema é que os elementos dos seu objeto `ativos2` não têm duas dimensões (linhas e colunas), e então a função `colnames()` não tem colunas à extrair. Dê uma olhada na `class()` dos seus objetos dentro la lista:
`for(i in 1:NROW(ativos2) class(ativos2[[i]])`