# Converter string para data no SparkR - Databricks

Tags: r, spark

Estou tratando um `dataframe` no algorítimo **prophet** em meu trabalho, para tanto no **Rstudio** utilizava o seguinte código para converter os dados de `Data` que estão como `string` para `Date`, pois o algorítimo necessita deste formato para fazer suas previsões.

```
Feriados$Data <- as.Date(Feriados$Data, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Porém quando rodo este código no **SparkR** ele me retorna o campo com valores `null` ou detalha este erro

```
Error in as.Date.default(Feriados$Data, "%d/%m/%Y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'Feriados$Data' to class “Date”
```

Conseguem me ajudar?

<sup>[`printSchema(Feriados)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE0GD.png)</sup>
<sup>[`select * from feriados`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd3bj.png)</sup>

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow! Dê uma olhada em [como melhorar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r) para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Em especial, compartilhar o resultado de `dput(head(Feriados$Data, 30))` pode nos ajudar.