# Mudar <chr> para número no R

Tags: r

Meus caros, estou tentando converter os dados das colunas 4 e 5 para número, mas está dando esse erro. Alguma sugestão?
Obrigado desde já!

[image: Erro ao converter <chr> para número no R]

```
library(tidyverse)

dadosarrumados <- data_frame(
  Região = c("Brasil", "Norte", "Rondônia", "Acre", "Amazonas"),
  Total = c(102083, 6715, 711, 285, 1597),
  `Anos de estudo` = rep("menor que 4 anos", 5),
  Quantidade = c("5068.075", "348.574", "42.42", "18.042", "73.231"),
  Porcentagem = c("5", "5.2", "6", "6.3", "4.")
)

as.numeric(dadosarrumados[, c(4, 5)])
```

> Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Tente isso: `library(tidyverse)`  `dadosarrumados%>%mutate_at(c('Quantidade','Porcentagem'),as.numeric)`.
Note que `dbl` é uma variável numérica.

Comment: Sugiro que edite a sua pergunta com este comando no `r`: `dput(dadosarrumados)` e poste aqui. Se seus dados forem muito grandes: `dput(head(dadosarrumados))`. Isso eviratá o fechamento da sua pergunta.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow! Dê uma olhada em [como melhorar sua próxima pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r) para que seja mais fácil ajudá-lo.

Answer (score 5):

Eu faria assim:

```
library(tidyverse)
dadosarrumados %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Quantidade, Porcentagem), parse_number)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
Região    Total `Anos de estudo` Quantidade Porcentagem
<chr>     <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>       <dbl>
  1 Brasil   102083 menor que 4 anos     5068.          5  
2 Norte      6715 menor que 4 anos      349.          5.2
3 Rondônia    711 menor que 4 anos       42.4         6  
4 Acre        285 menor que 4 anos       18.0         6.3
5 Amazonas   1597 menor que 4 anos       73.2         4
```

A vantagem de usar `parse_number` ao invés de `as.numeric` é que ela possui diversas outras opções, por exemplo, especificar qual é separador de decimais e de milhares:

```
> parse_number(c("1,10"), locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))
[1] 1.1

> as.numeric("1,1")
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Além de funcionar em outros contextos:

```
> parse_number("1%")
[1] 1
> as.numeric("1%")
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Um possível problema no seu caso é que valores omissos vieram com algum caractere indesejado ao invés de vazio, pode ser um `.` ou alguma coisa assim. Neste caso você poderia usar o argumento `na` da `parse_number` e fazer assim:

```
dadosarrumados %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Quantidade, Porcentagem), ~parse_number(.x, na = c(".")))
```

**note** `parse_number` é uma função do pacote `readr` que está dentro do `tidyverse`.

Comment: Esta solução é mais elegante mesmo.

Comment: Algum motivo para o `"."` estar dentro do `c()` no último código?

Comment: é como se o `.` fosse o caractere que usaram para missing na planilha

Comment: Esse é o motivo para ser passado para o argumento `na`, não para estar dentro de um `c( )`. Até onde entendo `c(".") == "."`

Comment: ah sim! então motivo nenhum, é só pra lembrar que pode passar um vetor ali.

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que o `R` entende que `dadosarrumados[, c(4, 5)]` é uma lista:

```
is.list(dadosarrumados[, c(4, 5)])
[1] TRUE
```

Uma maneira de resolver este problema é desfazer a lista e aí sim converter para numérico:

```
as.numeric(unlist(dadosarrumados[, c(4, 5)]))
[1] 5068.075  348.574   42.420   18.042   73.231    5.000    5.200    6.000
[9]    6.300    4.000
```

Mas veja que saímos de um problema e caímos em outro: perdemos a formatação que havia em duas colunas. A função `unlist` transformou o conjunto de dados em um vetor. Poderíamos transformar este vetor em data frame, mas eu prefiro outra abordagem.

Use a função `apply`. Ela serve para aplicar outras funções em colunas ou linhas de data frames. Por exemplo, ao rodar

```
apply(dadosarrumados[, c(4, 5)], 2, as.numeric)
     Quantidade Porcentagem
[1,]   5068.075         5.0
[2,]    348.574         5.2
[3,]     42.420         6.0
[4,]     18.042         6.3
[5,]     73.231         4.0
```

eu estou dizem para o `R` aplicar (`apply`) a função `as.numeric` nas colunas (número `2`) do data frame `dadosarrumados[, c(4, 5)]`. Se eu tivesse utilizado `1` em vez de `2` no segundo argumento de `apply`, a função `as.numeric` teria sido aplicada nas linhas e aí não teríamos o resultado desejado.

Uma maneira de obter o data frame completo, com as colunas convertidas para numérico, é fazendo assim:

```
bind_cols(dadosarrumados[, 1:3],
          as_data_frame(apply(dadosarrumados[, c(4, 5)], 2, as.numeric)))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Região    Total `Anos de estudo` Quantidade Porcentagem
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Brasil   102083 menor que 4 anos     5068.          5  
2 Norte      6715 menor que 4 anos      349.          5.2
3 Rondônia    711 menor que 4 anos       42.4         6  
4 Acre        285 menor que 4 anos       18.0         6.3
5 Amazonas   1597 menor que 4 anos       73.2         4
```

Eu estou usando a função `bind_cols` para juntar dois data frames: o original, das colunas 1 a 3, e o resultante da conversão que fizemos acima.