# Como fazer Classificação Hierárquica Descendente (CHD)/método de Reinert no R?

Tags: r, analise-de-texto

No `Iramuteq` tem uma análise bem comum, que é a *Classificação Hierárquica Descendente (CHD)* ou também conhecido por *método de Reinert*. 
Segue exemplo do que se trata a mesma: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9xliY7Zy40

Ela agrupa textos parecidos, criando novas "seções" (similar a análise fatorial).

1. Como posso fazer a mesma no R?
2. Tem algum nome em inglês para a mesma?

Segue um exemplo da mesma:

Inicia-se a análise com o seu corpus Textual:

```
library(quanteda)
dfm1 <- dfm(data_corpus_irishbudget2010)
```

e a partir dele (imagino eu), reproduz-se a CHD que tem os seguintes resultados principais:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele cassifica o seu copurs/texto em diferentes seções (classes), semelhante aos fatores da análise fatorial. De forma que 30,4% do texto foi classificado na Classe 4, 28,4% foi classificado na Classe 3 (outro assunto). E as mesmas tem uma interpretação prática, conforme as palavras mais frequentes que aparecem em cada classe, e é apresentado abaixo a outra tabela bem comum:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme a palavra/atributo que aparece na classe, eles dão nome para a classe, como por exemplo, a Classe 4 trata-se sobre aspectos nutricionais, pois as palavras que aparecem conjuntamente basicamente consistem em alimentos.

Comment: Precisa ser esta classificação hierárquica ou pode ser outro método? Sobre Clusterização hierárquicas no `R`, veja `?hclust`.

Comment: é que eu vou aplicar a técnica em dados que foram coletados sobre uma mesa rendonda, isto é, texto. Eu até pensei calcular alguma distância a partir do `dfm` que é gerado na mineração de textos, e aí aplicar o `hclust`, mas não é a mesma coisa. Essa técnica, pelo que eu entendi, agrupa os textos dentro de uma seção, e em seguida, informa qual palavra está associada com a seção a partir do Qui-Quadrado

Comment: Busque [melhorar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264168/43953), oferecendo um exemplo reprodutível e como quer o resultado esperado.

Comment: alterei @TomásBarcellos, mas eu não sei muito mais que isso

Comment: OP, eu não sou muito dessa área mas eu já usei um algorítimo de classificação de texto que faz algo similar a sua pergunta, dá uma olhada nesse capítulo aqui [aqui](https://www.tidytextmining.com/topicmodeling.html).

Comment: Obrigado @JdeMello, utilizei o seu conselho, e conseguir finalizar a análise com esse tipo de modelagem. Pelo nome do título da pergunta não encontrei nada no R.

Comment: Em breve deve pintar um pacote. https://juba.github.io/rainette/

Comment: O que se encontra mais próximo do que você quer talvez esteja neste pacote:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rainette/vignettes/introduction_en.html