# Como gerar e decompor uma Série Temporal no R?

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Estou com dificuldade em gerar e decompor uma Série Temporal. No caso, eu consegui criar uma série temporal `ts`, mas quando fui decompor a série `decompose`, indica que há um erro na Série Temporal, que diz que a Série Temporal não tem período, ou tem menos de 2.

Estou usando a coleção de pacotes do `tidyverse`.
Os "`dados_base`" possuem as 3 colunas (`USUARIO`;`DATA`;`VL_PED_PG`), no qual representam os Usuários, a Data de compra e o Valor, respectivamente.

Eu usei `summarise` para sumarizar os dados, para encontrar a quantidade de vendas por dia.

```
dados_dia = dados_base %>%
      group_by(DATA) %>%
      summarise(QTDE_COMPRAS = n(), VALOR_TOTAL = sum(VL_PED_PG))
```

Depois criei a Série Temporal.

```
compras = ts(dados_dia$QTDE_COMPRAS, start = c(2018,7), end = c(2019,1), frequency = 180)
```

Mas quando vou decompor(`decompose`) a Série Temporal sinaliza o erro.

```
dec = decompose(compras)
```

> Error in decompose(compras) : 
>         série temporal não tem período, ou tem menos de 2

`dput` para auxiliar a resposta:

```
structure(list(USUARIO = c(931053L, 276977L, 354508L, 909717L, 69758L, 
104827L, 6600051L, 5035952L, 335505L, 340387L, 103130L, 317058L, 
424447L, 6862455L, 5040771L), DATA = structure(c(17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731), class = "Date"), VL_PED_PG = c(20, 20, 50, 20.32, 20, 
30, 50, 50, 50, 50, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Olá, Isac. Não seria melhor editar a [questão antiga](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/357472/erro-na-decomposi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-uma-s%C3%A9rie-temporal) em vez de fazer uma nova pergunta?

Comment: Olá! Bom, na verdade eu não sei, eu sou novo na comunidade e estou aprendendo a a usá-la ainda. Mas aceito sugestões de como fazer as perguntas. Deu pra entender meu problema? Devo esclarecer mais alguma coisa?

Comment: Use este comando no `r`: `dput(dados_base)` ou `head(dput(dados_base))`. Após, copie e cole o resultado na pergunta.

Comment: Olá, eu tentei aqui, mas não consegui. tentei no R:
  
`teste_overflow = dput(dados_base)

compras = ts(teste_overflow, start = c(2018,7), end = c(2019,1), frequency = 60)

dec = decompose(compras)

Error in filter(x, filter) : 
  'filter' está mais comprido do que série temporal`

Eu não entendi como funciona.

Comment: Suponha que o nome do seu banco de dados seja `meusdados`. O que você precisa fazer é apenas isso: `dput(meusdados)` Só colocar `meusdados` dentro da função `dput`.

Comment: Eu tentei:

`teste_overflow = dput(dados_dia)

compras = ts(dados_dia$QTDE_COMPRAS, start = c(2018,7), end = c(2019,1), frequency = 60)`

e também:

`compras = ts(dput(dados_dia$QTDE_COMPRAS), start = c(2018,7), end = c(2019,1), frequency = 60)`

mas sem sucesso... Continua com o mesmo erro. Eu acho que não entendi como funciona. Você tem um exemplo de como usar o `dput` ?

Comment: Leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r). Isto pode ajudar.

Comment: Olá, acho q comecei a entender... seria isso?

`dput(head(dados_base, 15))
structure(list(USUARIO = c(931053L, 276977L, 354508L, 909717L, 
69758L, 104827L, 6600051L, 5035952L, 335505L, 340387L, 103130L, 
317058L, 424447L, 6862455L, 5040771L), DATA = structure(c(17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 
17731, 17731, 17731, 17731, 17731), class = "Date"), VL_PED_PG = c(20, 
20, 50, 20.32, 20, 30, 50, 50, 50, 50, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30)), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou utilizar um conjunto de dados que eu tenho (`data`), só para exemplificar:

```
data=structure(list(t = structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28), format.spss = "F8.0"), sales = structure(c(500, 350, 
250, 400, 450, 350, 200, 300, 350, 200, 150, 400, 550, 350, 250, 
550, 550, 400, 350, 600, 750, 500, 400, 650, 850, 600, 450, 700
), format.spss = "F8.2"), YEAR_ = structure(c(1990, 1990, 1990, 
1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1993, 1993, 
1993, 1993, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 
1996, 1996, 1996), label = "YEAR, not periodic", format.spss = "F8.0", 
display_width = 10L), 
QUARTER_ = structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), label = "QUARTER, period 4", 
format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 10L), 
DATE_ = structure(c("Q1 1990", "Q2 1990", "Q3 1990", "Q4 1990", 
"Q1 1991", "Q2 1991", "Q3 1991", "Q4 1991", "Q1 1992", "Q2 1992", 
"Q3 1992", "Q4 1992", "Q1 1993", "Q2 1993", "Q3 1993", "Q4 1993", 
"Q1 1994", "Q2 1994", "Q3 1994", "Q4 1994", "Q1 1995", "Q2 1995", 
"Q3 1995", "Q4 1995", "Q1 1996", "Q2 1996", "Q3 1996", "Q4 1996"
), label = "Date.  Format:  \"QQ YYYY\"", format.spss = "A7", display_width = 
9L)), .Names = c("t", 
"sales", "YEAR_", "QUARTER_", "DATE_"), row.names = c(NA, -28L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Vou criar uma série tempora com a variável `sales`, a qual vou chamar de `x`:

```
x<-ts(data$sales,start=c(2000,1),freq=12)
x
#     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2000 500 350 250 400 450 350 200 300 350 200 150 400
2001 550 350 250 550 550 400 350 600 750 500 400 650
2002 850 600 450 700
```

Agora, eu aplico a função de decomposição:

```
decompose(x)
```

E o resultado é emitido.

Então, qual é o problema com o seu caso?
Seguinte: você está introduzindo uma frequência (`frequency`) incoerente com o argumento `start` e o argumento `end`. Vamos voltar ao meu exemplo, mas com uma modificação. Vou colocar `freq=15` ao invés de `freq=12`:

```
x<-ts(data$sales,start=c(2000,1),freq=15)

decompose(x)
```

> Error in decompose(x) : time series has no or less than 2 periods

Por que esse erro ocorre? Por que a variável `sales` tem 28 linhas. E eu apliquei uma frequência de 15. Assim, 15*2=30. Logo, minha série tem menos de dois períodos. Se eu colocasse, por exemplo, 14, 13, 12 ... a decomposição seria calculada.

Desta forma, você deve ajustar o seu período (`freq`), pois ele está incoerente com as datas espeficadas em `start` e `end`. No seu exemplo, sua série começa em julho de 2018 e vai até janeiro de 2019 com uma frequência de 180.

Comment: Entendi. Agora funcionou perfeitamente.