# transformar numeros em frequência relativa

Tags: r, table, conversão

Caros, tenho a seguinte tabela com números absolutos:

```
structure(
  list(
    X = c("Ver_suj", "Ver_obj", "Substantivo", "Adjetivo" ), 
    Bolsonaro = c(59L, 299L, 988L, 653L), 
    Ciro = c(188L, 242L,  128L, 212L), 
    Manuela = c(59L, 66L, 1024L, 629L), 
    Marina = c(87L,  135L, 741L, 28L)
  ), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L )
)
```

que eu gostaria de transformar em números proporcionais, cujo resultado seria (seguindo a fórmula `n / sum(n)`:
[image: Tabela final]

Qual seria o melhor caminho?

Grato

Comment: Que tal compartilhar os dados com `dput(dados)`? Veja mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/) sobre como melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado, vou realizar isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat <- structure(
  list(
    X = c("Ver_suj", "Ver_obj", "Substantivo", "Adjetivo" ), 
    Bolsonaro = c(59L, 299L, 988L, 653L), 
    Ciro = c(188L, 242L,  128L, 212L), 
    Manuela = c(59L, 66L, 1024L, 629L), 
    Marina = c(87L,  135L, 741L, 28L)
  ), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L )
)
```

Resolvendo através de **apply:**

```
dat[, -1] <- apply(dat[, -1], 2, function(x) {x/sum(x)})
dat
            X  Bolsonaro      Ciro    Manuela     Marina
1     Ver_suj 0.02951476 0.2441558 0.03318335 0.08779011
2     Ver_obj 0.14957479 0.3142857 0.03712036 0.13622603
3 Substantivo 0.49424712 0.1662338 0.57592801 0.74772957
4    Adjetivo 0.32666333 0.2753247 0.35376828 0.02825429
```

O apply é uma função vetorizada, então para cada coluna "x", que é a entrada da função, ele vai pegar a coluna e dividir pela soma dela.

Answer (score 4):

Reproduzindo os dados

```
dados <- structure(
  list(
    X = c("Ver_suj", "Ver_obj", "Substantivo", "Adjetivo" ), 
    Bolsonaro = c(59L, 299L, 988L, 653L), 
    Ciro = c(188L, 242L,  128L, 212L), 
    Manuela = c(59L, 66L, 1024L, 629L), 
    Marina = c(87L,  135L, 741L, 28L)
  ), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L )
)
```

Desde a última versão do [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr), é possível usar a notação de fórmula dentro do mutate. Assim temos,

```
dados %>% 
  mutate_at(-1, ~.x/sum(.x))
#             X  Bolsonaro      Ciro    Manuela     Marina
# 1     Ver_suj 0.02951476 0.2441558 0.03318335 0.08779011
# 2     Ver_obj 0.14957479 0.3142857 0.03712036 0.13622603
# 3 Substantivo 0.49424712 0.1662338 0.57592801 0.74772957
# 4    Adjetivo 0.32666333 0.2753247 0.35376828 0.02825429
```

O que esta "sentença" quer dizer é "Faça uma mutação em todos as colunas **menos a primeira coluna**. Esta mutação será **dividir cada número pela soma dos números da coluna**".

A primeira parte em negrito é determinada pelo `-1` na função e a segunda é determinada pela fórmula `~.x / (sum.x)`. Nesta fórmula `.x` é uma representação genérica para cada valor do vetor (coluna)

#### Alternativa

Na versão mais tradicional do `dplyr` o comum seria definir uma função que retorna os percentuais e usa-la em um `mutate_at()` ou `mutate_if()`. Algo assim:

```
percentual <- function(n) {
  n / sum(n)
}

dados %>% 
  mutate_if(is.integer, percentual)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Sou iniciante e sofro muito ainda

Comment: Só uma pergunta, por que o ~ antes da fórmula?

Comment: É justamente o `~` que transforma o código que segue em fórmula. Isso permite ao `purrr` saber como lidar com ela (tratar, por exemplo, o `.x` como cada valor passado no primeiro argumento, etc)

Comment: [Neste material](https://www.curso-r.com/material/purrr/) explica um pouco do uso de fórmulas no `purrr`.