# Como winsorizar base de dados por grupo

Tags: r

Como winsorizar dados quando a base está por grupo?
Exemplo:

```
Empresas  Setores    Receita
Empres1   Comercio     ###
Empres2   Comercio     ###
Empres3   Comercio     ###
Empres21  Industria    ###
Empres22  Industria    ###
Empres23  Industria    ###
```

Comment: Por favor, crie um exemplo reproduzível. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r

Answer (score 0):

Vou usar a função `winsor` do pacote `psych` para winsorizar os dados.
Para responder à pergunta, basta usar uma das formas que o R tem de aplicar funções por grupos.

**R base.**

Com R base a função `ave` foi feita para isso.

```
library(psych)

with(dados, ave(Receita, Setores, FUN = winsor))
#[1] 518.6 857.0 899.0 318.8 632.0 801.2
```

Ou, criando uma nova coluna, numa cópia da base.

```
dados_a <- dados
dados_a$ReceitaWinsor <- with(dados, ave(Receita, Setores, FUN = winsor))
```

**Pacote `dplyr`.**

Com o pacote `dplyr` também não é difícil.

```
library(psych)
library(dplyr)

dados_b <- dados %>%
  group_by(Setores) %>%
  mutate(ReceitaWinsor = winsor(Receita))

dados_b
## A tibble: 6 x 4
## Groups:   Setores [2]
#  Empresas Setores   Receita ReceitaWinsor
#  <fct>    <fct>       <int>         <dbl>
#1 Empres1  Comercio      293          519.
#2 Empres2  Comercio      857          857 
#3 Empres3  Comercio      927          899 
#4 Empres21 Industria     110          319.
#5 Empres22 Industria     632          632 
#6 Empres23 Industria     914          801.
```

Apesar de os valores apresentados por esta segunda solução não parecerem ser os mesmos que os resultados do R base, de fato isso é só um arredondamento feito pelo `dplyr`.

```
identical(dados_a$ReceitaWinsor, dados_b$ReceitaWinsor)
#[1] TRUE
```

**Dados.**

Como os dados da pergunta estão incompletos, aqui vai uma base com as três colunas. As duas primeiras colunas são as da pergunta e a terceira será gerada aleatoriamente.

```
dados <-
structure(list(Empresas = structure(c(1L, 2L, 6L, 
3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Empres1", "Empres2", 
"Empres21", "Empres22", "Empres23", "Empres3"), 
class = "factor"), Setores = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Comercio", "Industria"), 
class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = "data.frame")

set.seed(1234)
dados$Receita <- sample(10:1000, 6, TRUE)
```