# Linguagem R: Como tirar números científicos dos gráficos?

Tags: r, barplot

## data frame tirado desse comando na base:

```
mes = base_final %>%
group_by(mes)%>%
summarise(soma_trs = sum(valor_trs))
```

## dataframe

```
mes <- data.frame(mes=c ("agosto/2017" , "setembro/2017", 
"outubro/2017") , soma_trs=c( 158491307 , 343986834 , 
922607132 ))
```

## Plot

## utilizei este comando para fazer um gráfico de barras

```
ggplot(mes,aes(x = mes, y = soma_trs))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue") +
labs(title = '                             Valor Total de 
Transações')
```

o problema que no gráfico, os valores y estão como números cientificos, os valores são altos mesmo devido o tamanho da base.
Como melhorar a visualização da base?

## preciso também por quantidade de transação, utilizei o table na base

## data.frame

```
qtd_trs <- data.frame (mes=c ("agosto/2017" , "setembro/2017", 
"outubro/2017") , qtd = c( 1157048 , 2327304 , 5966050)
```

## plot

```
barplot(table(qtd_trs$mes), col = "blue", main = "Número de 
Transações por Mês" )
```

Aconteceu o mesmo problema. Qual a melhor maneira de converter esses valores?

Comment: vc poderia oferecer um exemplo reproduzível do seu dataset? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu problema é apenas a notação científica, você pode fazer este ajuste pelo `options`. Tente isso:

```
options(scipen = 999)
```

Este valor alto (`999`) evita o retorno dos números em notação científica.

Comment: Obrigada Funcionou!