# Alterar escala no R

Tags: r

Estou tentando colocar uma escala no gráfico, mas ela fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ficasse `0`, `0.05`, `0.5`, `1`, `5`, `10`, `50` e `100`, não desta forma que estão no eixo X.

O código que usei foi esse:

```
plot(model2)
plot(model2, broken=FALSE, xlab="Dose (ppm)", ylab="Crescimento micelial (mm)", main="EC50")
plot(model2, axes=F)
axis(1,at=c(0, 0.05, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100))
axis(2,at=c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100))
ED(model2, respLev=50, interval = "delta")
```

Comment: Gostaria que ficasse 0, 0.05, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50 e 100, não desta forma que estão no eixo x.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Linguagem R: Como tirar números científicos dos gráficos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/386725/linguagem-r-como-tirar-n%c3%bameros-cient%c3%adficos-dos-gr%c3%a1ficos)

Answer (score 1):

Você não quer utilizar a notação científica, certo?

Encontrei uma pergunta antiga aqui que pode ter uma solução para você.

[Linguagem R: Como tirar números científicos dos gráficos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/386725/linguagem-r-como-tirar-n%C3%BAmeros-cient%C3%ADficos-dos-gr%C3%A1ficos)

A solução é utilizar

```
options(scipen = 999)
plot(model2)
```

Nunca utilizei, mas pelo que entendi funciona dessa forma.

Comment: Show de bola, deu certinho! Só que os outros números por ex 1 fica 1,00, com números após a virgula