# Como ordenar de maneira Crescente e decrescente em R?

Tags: r

Vamos supor

```
unique(base$workclass)#Checando os valores dos atributos das colunas, instâcias,linhas ou registros  
unique(base$workclass)# o resultado de apenas unico valor como seria a  ordem decrescente ou crescente :(
[1]  State-gov         Self-emp-not-inc  Private         
[4]  Federal-gov       Local-gov         Self-emp-inc    
[7]  Without-pay     
7 Levels:  Federal-gov  Local-gov  Private ...  Without-pay
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a função `sort` do `R base`:

```
sort(base$workclass)
```

Para ordenar de maneira decrescente, é preciso inserir o argumento `decreasing = TRUE`:

```
sort(base$workclass, decreasing = TRUE)
```

Você também pode utilizar a função `arrange` do `dplyr`. Porém, só é possível utilizá-la em `data.frames` ou `tibbles`. Considere o conjunto de dados abaixo:

```
data <- data.frame(
  a = c('d', 'j', 'a', 'k'), 
  b = 1:4
)
```

Ordenando (pela variável `a`) de forma crescente:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  arrange(a)

#  a b
#1 a 3
#2 d 1
#3 j 2
#4 k 4
```

De maneira decrescente:

```
data %>% 
  arrange(desc(a))

#  a b
#1 k 4
#2 j 2
#3 d 1
#4 a 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Também é possível realizar esta ação com o pacote `data.table`.

```
# df exemplo
set.seed(1)
LL <- c(sample(1:10, size = 2, replace = T),
        sample(1:10, size = 5, replace = T))
base <- data.frame(work_clss = c(LETTERS[1:10], 
                                 LETTERS[LL]),
                   id = 1:17,
                   n = sample(1:100, size = 17, replace = T))
```

```
library(data.table)
base <- data.table::data.table(base)
```

- `work_class` crescente

```
base[order(rank(work_clss))]

base[order(work_clss, decreasing = FALSE),]
```

- `work_class` decrescente

```
base[order(-rank(work_clss))]

base[order(work_clss, decreasing = TRUE),]
```

---

Considerando `unique(base$workclass)` é necessário transformar essa informação em classe *data frame* e posteriormente transforma-la em *data.table*:

Ex.: Utilizando o quadro de dados fictício.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
LL <- c(sample(1:10, size = 2, replace = T),
        sample(1:10, size = 5, replace = T))
base <- data.frame(workclass = c(LETTERS[1:10], 
                                 LETTERS[LL]),
                   id = 1:17,
                   n = sample(1:100, size = 17, replace = T))
table(base$workclass) # verificando as letras/palavras/fatores repetidos
```

```
> table(base$workclass)

A B C D E F G H I J 
1 1 3 2 1 2 1 1 2 3
```

```
df <- as.data.frame(unique(base$workclass)) # transformando em data frame
colnames(df) <- "workclass"                 # ajustando o nome da coluna
df <- data.table::data.table(df)            # transformando em data.table
df[order(rank(workclass))]                  # Ajustando em ordem crescente
```

```
> df[order(rank(workclass))]
    workclass
 1:         A
 2:         B
 3:         C
 4:         D
 5:         E
 6:         F
 7:         G
 8:         H
 9:         I
10:         J
```

```
table(df$workclass)
```

```
> table(df$workclass)

A B C D E F G H I J 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: sim , mas como eu integro com unique (base$workclass)*** mostra para mim  todos os registros .porém quero mostrar-los nas ordem

Comment: Vou editar a resposta e na parte final colocarei um exemplo didático.

Comment: Em caso de maiores dúvidas, verifique este [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) e forneça dados ao ponto de seu problema ser reproduzível.

Comment: obrigado ajudou muito!