# Filtro com 2 condições variáveis

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Tenho dois banco de dados, o primeiro tem umas 30 mil linhas o segundo 571.

Preciso filtrar o primeiro com duas condições do segundo banco.

Condição A: fctr seja `==`

Condição B: data `<=`

Tentei fazer um for duplo mas não deu certo.

Exemplo:

```
df1 = c(col1(a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c),col2("10/02", "15/02", "14/03", "05/03", "07/03", "15/03", "20/03", "12/03", "15/03"))

df2 = c(col1(a,b,c), col2("15/02", "15/03", "15/03"))
```

Preciso de algo do tipo:

```
filter(df1, col1 == [i]df2.col1 & col2 <= [i]df2.col2)
```

Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você poderia fornecer um exemplo reproduzível? [LINK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)
Mas, a priori, acho que seus df devem ter a mesma quantidade de linhas para realizar a ação da maneira que você idealizou.

Comment: Você tá tentando criar várias tabelas ou uma só? Tente deixar mais claro o objetivo, por favor. E dê uma olhada nos  que terminam com _join do dlpyr que talvez ajudem na comparação das duas tabelas.

Comment: Rafael, o código que você postou não é reproduzível. Verifique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os dados da pergunta estão numa linguagem (?) que não é o R nem outra que eu conheça, mas creio que com algum esforço se percebe o que é pretendido.

1. Os valores de `col1` devem ser iguais nas duas tabelas.
2. Os valores de `col2` da primeira não podem ser maiores que os da segunda.

Para obter valores iguais de `col1` vou fazer um `merge` por essa coluna e depois obter um índice lógico a partir da comparação de `col2`. Mas estas colunas parecem ser datas, portanto um passo preliminar será transformá-las em datas com `as.Date`.

```
tmp <- merge(df1, df2, by = "col1")
i <- apply(tmp[-1], 1, function(x){
  x <- as.Date(paste(x, "2000", sep = "/"), "%d/%m/%Y")
  x[1] <= x[2]
})
rm(tmp)

df1[i, ]
#  col1  col2
#1    a 10/02
#2    a 15/02
#4    b 05/03
#5    b 07/03
#6    b 15/03
#8    c 12/03
#9    c 15/03
```

**Dados.**

```
df1 = data.frame(col1 = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c"),
                 col2 = c("10/02", "15/02", "14/03", "05/03", "07/03", "15/03", "20/03", "12/03", "15/03"))

df2 = data.frame(col1 = c("a","b","c"), 
                 col2 = c("15/02", "15/03", "15/03"))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Já tinha pegado a solução no stack em inglês. Sua solução funciona também, é até mais elegante. Grande Abç!