# Separação de linhas em colunas em R

Tags: r

Amigos,estou aprendendo `R`. Estou selecionando os maiores consumidores de alguns tipos de bebida na América do Sul. Preciso separar o dataframe abaixo nas seguintes colunas: `pais`, `bebida` e `litros`, com os devidos valores nas linhas (registros). Ex: `Pais = Venezuela, bebida = cerveja, litros = 333`. Podem ajudar?

```
structure(list(key = c("pais", "litros_cerveja", "pais.1", 
"litros_spirit", 
"pais.2", "litros_vinho", "pais.3", "litros_alcool_puro"), value = 
c("Venezuela", 
"333", "Guyana", "302", "Argentina", "221", "Argentina", "8.3"
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: [clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r).

Comment: Imagens são uma má maneira de postar dados ou código. Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`? Nota: `dados` é o nome da base, por exemplo de um data.frame.

Comment: opa... foi mal, ainda to aprendendo a usar o RStudio e o stack tb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um truque para selecionar linhas alternadas é usar um vetor lógico na indexação, o qual será reciclado por toda a extensão do data.frame:

```
dados.brutos <- structure(list(key = c("pais", "litros_cerveja", "pais.1", "litros_spirit", "pais.2", "litros_vinho", "pais.3", "litros_alcool_puro"), value = c("Venezuela", "333", "Guyana", "302", "Argentina", "221", "Argentina", "8.3" )), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

> dados.brutos[c(TRUE, FALSE), ]
     key     value
1   pais Venezuela
3 pais.1    Guyana
5 pais.2 Argentina
7 pais.3 Argentina
```

Separando os dados das linhas pares e ímpares e unindo-os como colunas distintas terá o que precisa:

```
dados.arrumados <- cbind(dados.brutos[c(TRUE, FALSE), 2], # 2 ou "value", para selecionar apenas a coluna com o nome dos países
                         dados.brutos[c(FALSE, TRUE), ] )
```

Para terminar, coloque os nomes adequados para as variáveis e remova o "litros" no começo do nome das bebidas (estou assumindo que todos os dados estejam em litros, caso contrário pule essa parte):

```
names(dados.arrumados) <- c("país", "bebida", "litros")
dados.arrumados$bebida <- gsub("^litros_", "", dados.arrumados$bebida)

> dados.arrumados
       país      bebida litros
2 Venezuela     cerveja    333
4    Guyana      spirit    302
6 Argentina       vinho    221
8 Argentina alcool_puro    8.3
```

Comment: Muito show. Obrigado