# mutate - case_when - RStudio

Tags: r

Preciso ajustar uma coluna em relação a outra.
Tenho uma coluna de hostpitais "HP" e uma coluna de cidades "City". Preciso ajustar a cidade conforme o Hospital. BWn é minha base de dados
Estou fazendo:

`BWn = BWn %>% mutate(City = case_when(str_detect (HP, "H.U.DE BELLVITGE”) ~ ”Barcelona”, str_detect (HP, “H.G.U.GREGORIO MARAÑÓN”) ~ ” Madrid”, str_detect (HP, “H.CLÍNIC”) ~ ” Barcelona”, str_detect (HP, “H.U.QUIRÓN DEXEUS”) ~ ” Barcelona”, TRUE ~ “Sevilla”))`

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

Mas, ao executar, ele aparece o "+", como se não tivesse finalizado...
O que estou fz errado? Há uma maneira mais simples de fazer?

Preciso que  os hospitais estejam relacionados com as cidades igual a tabel:
[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][2]][2]

`dput` dos dados:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:10, HP = c("H.G.U.GREGORIO MARAÑÓN", "H.U.DE BELLVITGE",
"H.U.DE BELLVITGE", "H.CLÍNIC", "H.U.12 DE OCTUBRE", "H.G.U.GREGORIO MARAÑÓN",
"H.M.I. VIRGEN DE LAS NIEVES", "C.U.NAVARRA", "H.U.LA PAZ", "C.U.NAVARRA"
), City = c("Valencia", "Barcelona", "Madrid", "Barcelona", "Madrid",
"Madrid", "Sevilla", "Pamplona", "Madrid", "Pamplona"), Time = structure(c(81L,
25L, 162L, 143L, 265L, 179L, 252L, 190L, 221L, 63L), .Label = c("0",
"1,87", "10,04", "10,09", "10,15", "10,25", "10,32", "10,4",
"10,46", "10,5", "10,54", "10,56", "10,61", "10,63", "10,66",
"10,68", "10,74", "10,75", "10,77", "10,83", "10,88", "10,9",
"10,94", "10,99", "11", "11,01", "11,05", "11,07", "11,13", "11,27",
"11,34", "11,38", "11,39", "11,49", "11,51", "11,56", "11,59",
"11,73", "11,78", "11,8", "11,83", "11,92", "11,94", "11,99",
"12,02", "12,06", "12,11", "12,13", "12,22", "12,23", "12,27",
"12,29", "12,32", "12,43", "12,49", "12,58", "12,63", "12,65",
"12,67", "12,72", "12,74", "12,81", "12,87", "12,94", "12,95",
"12,97", "12,98", "13,06", "13,08", "13,11", "13,12", "13,14",
"13,17", "13,18", "13,21", "13,22", "13,26", "13,27", "13,29",
"13,3", "13,34", "13,39", "13,43", "13,53", "13,54", "13,57",
"13,58", "13,61", "13,71", "13,73", "13,75", "13,78", "13,79",
"13,8", "13,92", "14", "14,01", "14,11", "14,12", "14,26", "14,28",
"14,33", "14,34", "14,69", "14,71", "14,72", "14,8", "14,81",
"14,82", "15", "15,07", "15,28", "15,29", "15,4", "15,46", "15,54",
"15,56", "15,93", "15,97", "16,04", "16,05", "16,1", "16,15",
"16,17", "16,2", "16,31", "16,35", "16,38", "16,43", "16,53",
"16,59", "16,96", "17,17", "17,32", "17,77", "17,82", "17,84",
"18,06", "18,1", "18,31", "18,46", "18,48", "18,64", "18,89",
"19,34", "19,54", "19,71", "19,8", "2,6", "2,64", "20,57", "20,85",
"21,29", "21,4", "21,43", "21,85", "22,16", "23", "23,15", "23,56",
"23,72", "24", "3,26", "3,43", "3,66", "3,73", "3,99", "4", "4,06",
"4,21", "4,26", "4,6", "4,76", "4,81", "5,39", "5,58", "5,6",
"5,65", "5,68", "5,69", "5,85", "6,26", "6,27", "6,42", "6,56",
"6,63", "6,66", "6,72", "6,84", "6,86", "6,92", "7,02", "7,11",
"7,14", "7,24", "7,27", "7,32", "7,34", "7,39", "7,4", "7,45",
"7,58", "7,65", "7,69", "7,73", "7,75", "7,77", "7,82", "7,94",
"7,98", "8", "8,01", "8,02", "8,07", "8,24", "8,26", "8,36",
"8,38", "8,41", "8,42", "8,43", "8,48", "8,51", "8,53", "8,63",
"8,67", "8,69", "8,7", "8,74", "8,77", "8,8", "8,81", "8,82",
"8,86", "8,91", "8,93", "8,94", "8,95", "8,96", "8,98", "9,05",
"9,16", "9,17", "9,19", "9,29", "9,35", "9,36", "9,42", "9,44",
"9,53", "9,54", "9,55", "9,57", "9,58", "9,63", "9,65", "9,66",
"9,69", "9,74", "9,8", "9,83", "9,84", "9,85", "9,87", "9,89",
"9,94", "9,98"), class = "factor"), Day = c(5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L,
6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L), BW = structure(c(25L, 89L, 86L, 9L, 6L,
78L, 50L, 73L, 51L, 52L), .Label = c("1.45 kg", "1.65 kg",
"1.7 kg", "1.804 kg", "1025 gr", "1150 gr", "1173 gr", "1250 gr",
"1300 gr", "1435 gr", "1450 gr", "1599 gr", "1650 gr", "1700 gr",
"1722 gr", "1750 gr", "1800 gr", "1950 gr", "2 kg", "2,05 kg",
"2,9 kg", "2,95 kg", "2.05 kg", "2.1976 kg", "2.2 kg", "2.35 kg",
"2.419 kg", "2.5 kg", "2.55 kg", "2.6 kg", "2.68 kg", "2.7 kg",
"2.75 kg", "2.8 kg", "2.87 kg", "2.9 kg", "2.95 kg", "2000 gr",
"2009 gr", "2050 gr", "2100 gr", "2132 gr", "2200 gr", "2250 gr",
"2255 gr", "2350 gr", "2378 gr", "2450 gr", "2460 gr", "2500 gr",
"2550 gr", "2600 gr", "2650 gr", "2680 gr", "2700 gr", "2750 gr",
"2800 gr", "2850 gr", "2870 gr", "2900 gr", "2950 gr", "3 kg",
"3.1 kg", "3.15 kg", "3.25 kg", "3.4 kg", "3.5 kg", "3.55 kg",
"3.6 kg", "3.8 kg", "3000 gr", "3050 gr", "3100 gr", "3150 gr",
"3200 gr", "3250 gr", "3300 gr", "3400 gr", "3500 gr", "3550 gr",
"3600 gr", "3650 gr", "3680 gr", "3800 gr", "4 kg", "4.2 kg",
"4.85 kg", "4000 gr", "4100 gr", "4200 gr", "4850 gr"), class = "factor"),
BPD = structure(c(8L, 23L, 23L, 5L, 3L, 20L, 13L, 18L, 12L,
19L), .Label = c("100 mm", "64 mm", "68 mm", "72 mm", "74 mm",
"80 mm", "81 mm", "82 mm", "83 mm", "84 mm", "85 mm", "86 mm",
"87 mm", "88 mm", "89 mm", "90 mm", "91 mm", "92 mm", "93 mm",
"94 mm", "95 mm", "96 mm", "97 mm"), class = "factor"), AD = structure(c(31L,
20L, 21L, 22L, 26L, 11L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 3L), .Label = c("100 mm",
"101 mm", "102 mm", "103 mm", "104 mm", "105 mm", "106 mm",
"107 mm", "108 mm", "109 mm", "110 mm", "112 mm", "113 mm",
"114 mm", "115 mm", "116 mm", "118 mm", "119 mm", "120 mm",
"129 mm", "133 mm", "71 mm", "73 mm", "78 mm", "79 mm", "80 mm",
"82 mm", "85 mm", "86 mm", "89 mm", "90 mm", "92 mm", "93 mm",
"94 mm", "95 mm", "96 mm", "97 mm", "98 mm", "99 mm"), class = "factor"),
Sex = structure(c(6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("boy",
"f", "F", "fem", "girl", "M"), class = "factor"), Ge = structure(c(1L,
11L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("32,8",
"33", "33,73", "34", "35,5", "37,29", "37,5", "39,2", "39,9",
"41,3", "43,2"), class = "factor"), Sm = structure(c(1L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "S"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA,
10L), class = "data.frame")


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNRpv.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44BpV.png
```

Comment: Tem os dados? Que sinal de `+`? Existe alguma mensagem de erro? Leia [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e edite a pergunta.

Comment: O sinal de + é o que destaquei em amarelo na foto... depois de digitar o código acima, dou enter e aparece o sinal "+", como se faltasse algo..

Comment: Fecha este código com um parêntesis no final: `)`. Esse "mais" significa que a função não foi terminada (a linha pede para que você termine ele com esse `+`).

Comment: Não tenho como mostrar os dados, mas, basicmente é: Quando o Hospitarl estiver com o nome "H.G.U.GREGORIO MARAÑÓN", preciso deixar a variável City = "Madrid", quando o hospital tiver o nome "H.U.DE BELLVITGE", a variável City = "Barcelona" e assim, sucessivamente...

Comment: Fechou o código com o `)`?

Comment: sim... não resolveu

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105852/discussion-between-neves-and-gisele-santos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código da pergunta tem dois problemas:

- As [aspas "inteligentes"](https://support.office.com/pt-pt/article/aspas-inglesas-no-word-702fc92e-b723-4e3d-b2cc-71dedaf2f343) ou curvas;
- Há espaços a mais nas strings alvo.

Corrigidos esses problemas funciona bem.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

BWn <- BWn %>% 
  mutate(City = case_when(
    str_detect(HP, "H.U.DE BELLVITGE") ~ "Barcelona", 
    str_detect(HP, "H.CLÍNIC") ~ "Barcelona", 
    str_detect(HP, "H.U.QUIRÓN DEXEUS") ~ "Barcelona", 
    str_detect(HP, "H.G.U.GREGORIO MARAÑÓN") ~ "Madrid", 
    TRUE ~ "Sevilla"))
```

As três primeiras colunas do resultado são as seguintes.

```
BWn[1:3]
#   ID                          HP      City
#1   1      H.G.U.GREGORIO MARAÑÓN    Madrid
#2   2            H.U.DE BELLVITGE Barcelona
#3   3            H.U.DE BELLVITGE Barcelona
#4   4                    H.CLÍNIC Barcelona
#5   5           H.U.12 DE OCTUBRE   Sevilla
#6   6      H.G.U.GREGORIO MARAÑÓN    Madrid
#7   7 H.M.I. VIRGEN DE LAS NIEVES   Sevilla
#8   8                 C.U.NAVARRA   Sevilla
#9   9                  H.U.LA PAZ   Sevilla
#10 10                 C.U.NAVARRA   Sevilla
```