# Qual uma acurácia boa?

Tags: r, series-temporais, forecast

Olá, sou um jovem estudante e tenho trabalhado sozinho num projeto. O projeto envolve vendas de carros (analisando a quantidade de carros vendidos) da Noruega de 2007 ate 2016. Quis tentar criar uma série temporal (Usei o ts), e em seguida usar criar um modelo de previsão usando Holt-Winters e Forecast.

[image: Um exemplo do dataset]

Na série temporal em si foi ate tranquilo, segue como ficou: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém na hora de fazer a previsão, usei o código:

```
ajuste_HW_CT_CS <- HoltWinters(z)
ajuste_HW_CT_CS
plot(ajuste_HW_CT_CS)


previsao <- forecast(ajuste_HW_CT_CS, h=36)
plot(previsao, main = "Previsão Venda de Carros Noruega 2017 - 2019", xlab = "Anos", ylab = "Quantidade de Carros Vendidos")
previsao
```

Achei que estaria tudo bem, segue imagem da previsao:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem ao usar:
`accuracy(previsao)`

Obtive:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu modelo estaria ruim, mal configurado ou algo do tipo? Infelizmente não sei interpretar, poderiam me ajudar? Não sei se as datas são muito curtas para haver treinamento ou deveria haver apenas uma coluna com a data, porém ainda não sei fazer isso.

Comment: Prezado @Vitor Resende, sua pergunta pode ser melhor colocada no ambiente do [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) do próprio SO, pois se trata da perspectiva analítica acerca de um produto/resultado. De todo modo, Seu exemplo não é [reproduzível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r), o q me impede de poder te ajudar de maneira mais assertiva.

Comment: Porém, analisando o plot e valores de RMSE e MAE, percebo um elevado range de forecast e estimativas de erro na ordem de 10% do valor referência (observado real, eixo y), que entendo como valores e casos que podem ser melhorados. Veja se [isto](https://otexts.com/fpp2/accuracy.html) te ajuda.

Comment: Vocês tem alguma leitura que possam indicar sobre isto ? Pretendo usar no QlikSense.

Comment: @bbiasi obrigado pelo link! Vai me ajudar bastante a estudar! Acho que é isso então, estudarei para tentar aplicar nesse projeto, a linguagem R me fascina muito!

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta com a saída de `dput(dados[1:20, c("Year", "Month", "Quantity")])`, por favor? Imagens não são uma boa maneira de partilhar dados e sem eles não podemos testar o código.

Comment: O modelo Holt-Winters considera tendência, inclinação e sazonalidade; a queda nas vendas entre 2008 e 2010 deve ser a responsável pela baixa acurácia. Considere usar outro modelo, como ARIMA ou BATS (ambos disponíveis no pacote *forecast*). Aqui tem [uma leitura rápida, com exemplos, de diferentes métodos](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-forecasting-in-r-6b0c9638c261). Mas como já indicado, é melhor perguntar no [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/forecasting), já que sua dúvida é sobre análise dos dados e não sobre programação.

Answer (score 0):

normalmente a  função `accuracy()` é utilizada quando se está comparando modelos, no seu caso você apenas utilizou a função para um modelo. Eu aconselho fazer sempre os testes de fac e facp para identificar as ordens dos modelos, bem como utilizar a função `auto.arima()` para checar o modelo mais ajustado segundo o machine learning do pacote `forecast`. Feito esses passos, há duas formas de checar o melhor modelo, segue:

1. Criar uma série de treinamento e checar se o modelo está bem ajustado com os valores reais. Isso pode ser feito preservando as 4 últimas observações, então você testa se a previsão se aproxima dos valores observados.
2. A segunda forma é utilizar a função que tu usaste, mas comparando os modelos. Feito os passos descritos mais acima, você pode utilizar a função `accuracy()` em uma lista de modelos e observar quais possuem os menores valores entre os testes.

Abraço!