# Problema em ler input do teclado com readline no R

Tags: r

Olá, to tentando fazer esse programinha ai no rstudio, porém qndo seleciono tudo para rodar, ele da esse erro. Se eu coloco para rodar a primeira linha e depois o resto, ai ele roda o programa certinho. Talvez seja algo besta que não estou sabendo. E nem esse e nem outros programas que faz no rstudio roda.

A seguir meu código:

```
 id = as.integer(readline(prompt = "Escreva sua idade: "))
  
 if(id >= 0 && id < 18){
   print("você é uma criança")
 }
 else if(id >= 18 && id <= 50){
   print("você é adulto")
 }
 else print("você é um adulto experiente")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sem um [exemplo reproduzível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) fica difícil ajudar, @Lenesson.

Comment: Dá ara ver na parte superior direita do RStudio que o id está com valor `NA` (`NA_integer_`). Isso causa o erro em questão. Veja como você está definindo essa variável

Comment: Parece que tem relação com todas as duas coisas direito, sem dar digitar o que um usuário digitaria na idade.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi do seu código, quando o programa fez a pergunta `Escreva sua idade:`

Você não digitou um inteiro válido (por exemplo, digitar uma string `a` ou apenas digitar `<enter>`), porém esse valor é necessário para executar o if. Já que o valor lido é armazenado na variável `id`.

O erro ocorre porque o valor `id` é nulo.

Uma maneira de tratar este erro é verificar se o valor lido é um inteiro válido antes de executar a lógica presente no `if`.

Comment: Quando eu rodo o programa todo (selecionando tudo e apertando em run) ele printa todo meu codigo, da esse erro antes mesmo de aparecer para eu digitar

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na primeira instrução. A função `readline` deve ser executada numa linha à parte, com ou sem `as.integer`. Senão, quando passa para a instrução seguinte está a enviar um `<Enter>` (seja `<CR>` seja `<CR><LF>`) automaticamente.

Execute a primeira linha de código, introduzindo um número.

Depois sim, pode seleccionar e executar todo o resto do código.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer que todo o código seja executado de uma vez, sem que o valor id seja atribuído à parte, você pode tentar uma abordagem funcional, transferindo o método para dentro de uma função. Assim:

```
verificadorIdade <- function(){
  id <- as.integer(readline(prompt = 'Escreva sua idade: '))
  
  if(id >= 0 && id < 18){
    print('você é uma criança')
  }
  else if(id >= 18 && id <= 50){
    print('você é adulto')
  }
  else print('você é um adulto experiente')
}
```

A única diferença aqui é que eu criei uma função, chamada `verificadorIdade` e coloquei seu código como método. Assim, quando você executar o comando `verificadorIdade()` o código vai funcionar perfeitamente. Lembre-se de executar a função antes, para que o R a salve na memória