# Aplicar uma função variando entre as categorias no R

Tags: r, group-by

Preciso calcular a elasticidade - preço da demanda de um produto em específico (variação percentual da quantidade demandada dividido pela variação percentual do preço). Para isso fiz a seguinte equação:

```
elasticidade = numeric(length(teste))
for(i in 2:nrow(teste)){
elasticidade[i] = ((media_vendas[i]-media_vendas[i-1])/(media_vendas[i]+media_vendas[i-1])/2)/((preço[i]-preço[i-1])/(preço[i]+preço)/2)
```

Em que `media_vendas` é a quantidade média de unidades vendidas por tal preço e `preço` é o preço da unidade no dia.

No entanto, gostaria de aplicar essa equação agrupando pelos dias da semana e preço, ou seja, calcular a elasticidade entre as observações para cada dia da semana para cada preço:

```
    dados %>% select(DiaSemana, preço, vendas) %>% 
  group_by(DiaSemana, preço) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), 
            media_vendas = mean(vendas)) %>%
  mutate(elasticidade = ((media_vendas[2]-media_vendas[1])/(media_vendas[2]+media_vendas[1])/2)/((preço[2]-preço[1])/(preço[2]+preço[1])/2), by = DiaSemana)
```

Colocando com o `for` dentro do `mutate` ou dessa forma, ambos não rodam.

```
  DiaSemana  preço          n media_vendas
       <chr> <chr>      <int>        <dbl>
     1 qua   1.55           7        166. 
     2 qua   1.69          18        123. 
     3 qua   1.99           6        103. 
     4 qua   2.59           2         99.5
     5 qui   1.55           8        204  
     6 qui   1.69          16        130. 
     7 qui   1.99           7        109. 
     8 seg   1.55           7        127. 
     9 seg   1.69          17        152. 
    10 seg   1.99           6         86.2
    11 seg   2.59           1        106  
    12 sex   1.55           7        193. 
    13 sex   1.69          15        182. 
    14 sex   1.99           7        111. 
    15 ter   1.55           7        134. 
    16 ter   1.69          19        135. 
    17 ter   1.99           5         91.8
    18 ter   2.59           2         90.5
```

Por exemplo, calcular a elasticidade a partir da média de vendas da quarta do preço 1.69 menos a média de vendas da quarta do preço 1.55. A média de vendas da quarta do preço 1.99 menos a média de vendas da quarta do preço 1.69, ...
E fazer isso para cada dia da semana.

Comment: Olá Leonardo, bem vindo ao SO em português. Leia as instruções sobre como fazer boas perguntas no site. Em especial, veja este tópico sobre como fornecer uma amostra dos seus dados em R: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro define-se uma função para calcular a elasticidade através do modelo linear. Para calcular diferenças, é necessário que cada vetor tenha pelo menos dois elementos, se não tiverem o resultado é indeterminado (`NA`) com uma mensagem.

```
elasticidade <- function(preco, quant){
  nome_preco <- deparse(substitute(preco))
  if(length(preco) < 2){
    msg <- paste(sQuote(nome_preco), "tem menos de dois elementos, o cálculo não pode ser efetuado.")
    message(msg)
    NA
  } else {
    preco.bar <- mean(preco, na.rm = TRUE)
    quant.bar <- mean(quant, na.rm = TRUE)
    fit <- lm(quant ~ preco)
    coef(fit)[2] * preco.bar/quant.bar
  }
}
```

Agora, aplica-se a função acima num pipe `dplyr`, agrupando por dia da semana. Acrescentei uma coluna não pedida na pergunta, `Elastico`, que pode tomar os valores

1. `"não"` - elasticidade menor que 1;
2. `"sim"` - elasticidade maior que 1;
3. `"unitário"` - elasticidade igual a 1.

Para não obter esta coluna basta remover as linhas do `mutate` e acabar o pipe logo na linha do `summarise`.

```
library(dplyr)

dados %>%
  group_by(DiaSemana) %>%
  summarise(Elasticidade = elasticidade(preço, media_vendas), .groups = 'keep') %>%
  mutate(Elastico = sign(abs(Elasticidade) - 1) + 2,
         Elastico = c("Não", "Unitário", "Sim")[Elastico])
## A tibble: 5 x 3
## Groups:   DiaSemana [5]
#  DiaSemana Elasticidade Elastico
#  <chr>            <dbl> <chr>   
#1 qua             -0.823 Não     
#2 qui             -2.28  Sim     
#3 seg             -0.556 Não     
#4 sex             -2.09  Sim     
#5 ter             -0.797 Não
```