# função summarise

Tags: r

Eu estou utilizando uma base de dados com informações sobre as olimpíadas(https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results) e estou querendo analisar os dados sobre os esportes olímpicos em que o Brasil foi medalhista. Eu utilizei a função summarize() para obter uma coluna com número de medalhas por esportes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas quando eu vou realizar o somatório dessa coluna eu obtenho o erro “Erro: objeto 'sum(total2)' não encontrado".

```
teste <- na.omit(subset(df1, select = c(Medal, Team, Sport, Event)))
teste <- teste %>% rename(pf = Sport)
teste <- teste %>% rename(pv = Medal)
data ＜- teste %＞% filter(Team=='Brazil') %>% 
        group_by(pv, pf) %＞% distinct(Event) %>% 
        summarize(total2 = n())
        sum(total2)
```

Já tentei a função `colSum` mas retorna o mesmo error.
Aproveitando o post, seria possível criar um pie chart com os esportes medalhistas? tentei fazer utilizando o `ggplot2` mas não consegui.

Comment: 1) Tente `sum(data$total2)`; 2) Porquê pie chart? Gráficos de barras são considerados melhores. 3) Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(data)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(data, 20))`? Ou então onde encontrar os dados originais.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Este é um site para responder questões práticas de programação, é importante fornecer além do seu código uma amostra dos dados que está usando. Leia mais sobre isso [neste tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) da Central de Ajuda. Veja também [esta postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) para detalhes sobre como fazer um exemplo mínimo em R.

Answer (score 3):

O seguinte código conta as medalhas que o Brasil teve nos Jogos Olímpicos.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)

fl <- list.files(pattern = 'athlete.*\\.csv$')
fl

cols_spec <- cols(
  ID = col_double(),
  Name = col_character(),
  Sex = col_character(),
  Age = col_double(),
  Height = col_double(),
  Weight = col_double(),
  Team = col_character(),
  NOC = col_character(),
  Games = col_character(),
  Year = col_double(),
  Season = col_character(),
  City = col_character(),
  Sport = col_character(),
  Event = col_character(),
  Medal = col_character()
)

df1 <- read_csv(fl, col_types = cols_spec)
```

Depois de ler o ficheiro, filtrar por país e agrupar os dados com `summarise`. O resultado, só com 2 colunas, é guardado no data.frame `cont_medalhas`.

```
df1 %>%
  filter(Team == 'Brazil') %>%
  select(Medal, Sport) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(Sport, Medal) %>%
  summarize(Total = n(), .groups = 'drop') -> cont_medalhas
```

Agora os totais. O Brasil teve ao todo 449 medalhas em 14 esportes (ou, tendo em conta que eu sou Português, *desportos*).

```
cont_medalhas %>% pull(Total) %>% sum()
#[1] 449

cont_medalhas %>% distinct(Sport) %>% nrow()
#[1] 14
```

Finalmente, o gráfico de barras. As cores vêm [deste post](https://www.schemecolor.com/olympic-medals-color-scheme.php).

```
cont_medalhas %>%
  mutate(Sport = factor(Sport),
         Medal = factor(Medal, levels = c('Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze'))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sport, Total, fill = Medal)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = 'single')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#FEE101', '#A7A7AD', '#A77044')) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Gostei da paleta de cores escolhida para as barras. Bastante temática.

Comment: @MarcusNunes Obrigado, incluí um link para o site onde as encontrei.