# Substituir NA, com base em outro data frame atraves de colunas iguais. R

Tags: r, dataframe

Tenho duas tabelas de dados. Gostaria de substituir os NAs da Tabela1 pelos valores da Tabela2 utilizando duas colunas de referencia que estão nas duas tabelas.
Gostaria de substituir *apenas* os NAs. Exemplo:

Tabela1

| Estado | Loja | compras |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SP | E01 | 5 |
| SP | E02 | NA |
| RJ | E01 | NA |
| MT | E03 | NA |

Tabela2

| Estado | Loja | compras |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SP | E01 | 3 |
| SP | E02 | 10 |
| RJ | E01 | 9 |
| RJ | E02 | 7 |
| MT | E03 | 4 |

```
Tabela1 <- structure(list(
  Estado = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("MT", "RJ", "SP"), class = "factor"),
  Loja = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("E01", "E02", "E03"), class = "factor"),
  compras = c(5L, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

Tabela2 <- structure(list(
  Estado = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("MT", "RJ", "SP"), class = "factor"),
  Loja = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("E01", "E02", "E03"), class = "factor"),
  compras = c(3L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Bem vinda ao SOpt. Sempre forneça o exemplo em um formato que seja facilmente lido por quem quiser te ajudar. Veja este tópico sobre como gerar exemplos reproduzíveis em R: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar `merge` para criar um data.frame com os dados da Tabela1 alinhados com os da Tabela2:

```
TabelaM <- merge(Tabela1, Tabela2,
             by = c("Estado", "Loja"),
             all.x = TRUE,
             suffix = c("", ".y"))

TabelaM
#>   Estado Loja compras compras.y
#> 1     MT  E03      NA         4
#> 2     RJ  E01      NA         9
#> 3     SP  E01       5         3
#> 4     SP  E02      NA        10
```

E então usar indexação lógica para identificar as linhas que possuem NA para `compras` e substituir pelos valores de `compras.y` (vindos da Tabela2):

```
nas <- is.na(TabelaM$compras)

TabelaM$compras[nas] <- TabelaM$compras.y[nas]

within(TabelaM, rm(compras.y))
#>   Estado Loja compras
#> 1     MT  E03       4
#> 2     RJ  E01       9
#> 3     SP  E01       5
#> 4     SP  E02      10
```

**Com dplyr**

O pacote *dplyr* tem a função `coalesce` para preencher NAs de uma coluna com valores de outra. Assim como na opção acima, primeiro une-se os dados da Tabela2 na Tabela1 para garantir a correspondência:

```
library(dplyr)

Tabela1 %>%
  left_join(Tabela2, by = c("Estado", "Loja"), suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  mutate(compras = coalesce(compras, compras.y)) %>%
  select(-compras.y)
#>   Estado Loja compras
#> 1     SP  E01       5
#> 2     SP  E02      10
#> 3     RJ  E01       9
#> 4     MT  E03       4
```

**Com data.table**

O pacote *data.table* possui a função `fcoalesce` ("fast coalesce") com a mesma finalidade. Como data.table trabalha por referência, a Tabela1 será modificada diretamente:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(Tabela1)
setDT(Tabela2)

Tabela1[Tabela2, on = .(Estado, Loja), compras := fcoalesce(compras, i.compras)]

Tabela1
#>    Estado Loja compras
#> 1:     SP  E01       5
#> 2:     SP  E02      10
#> 3:     RJ  E01       9
#> 4:     MT  E03       4
```