# Como renomear uma linha?

Tags: r

Tenho a tabela:

```
                                   [,1]
Inconclusivo ou indeterminado  1.229142
Negativo                      60.131108
Null                          11.536551
Positivo                      27.103198
```

Gostaria de renomear a linha Null.

Comment: Olá Cleonice, bem vinda ao SOpt. Por favor, edite sua pergunta para incluir a saída do comando `dput` para seu objeto com a tabela. Veja [este post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) para detalhes sobre como fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar `row.names` com indexação lógica para identificar a linha com nome "Null". Como não forneceu seus dados em um formato reproduzível, estou criando um exemplo simples:

```
# matriz de exemplo
tabela <- matrix(1:3, dimnames = list(c("A", "Null", "C")))

tabela
#>      [,1]
#> A       1
#> Null    2
#> D       3

row.names(tabela)[row.names(tabela) == "Null"] <- "B"

tabela
#>   [,1]
#> A    1
#> B    2
#> C    3
```