# Combinar valores recursivos em um dataframe com valores únicos no R

Tags: r, recursão, tidyverse

Tenho um banco de dados com identificações de animais (brincos). Alguns animais perdem esse brincos e, quando isto acontece, o brinco é reposto por outro brinco com outro id e esta informação fica contida em uma tabela similar a esta:

```
date<- c('2018-01-01','2018-02-20','2018-10-04','2018-12-30','2019-01-03','2019-03-14','2019-05-06','2019-07-01','2019-07-25','2019-10-29','2019-11-26','2020-01-07','2020-05-04','2020-12-30')
> id_brinco_or<-c(1,5,10,20,31,3,4,13,15,12,2,65,9,93)
> id_brinco_rp<-c(2,8,15,12,13,6,28,55,65,9,80,40,93,30)
> 
> df<-data.frame(date,id_brinco_or,id_brinco_rp)
> df
         date id_brinco_or id_brinco_rp
1  2018-01-01            1            2
2  2018-02-20            5            8
3  2018-10-04           10           15
4  2018-12-30           20           12
5  2019-01-03           31           13
6  2019-03-14            3            6
7  2019-05-06            4           28
8  2019-07-01           13           55
9  2019-07-25           15           65
10 2019-10-29           12            9
11 2019-11-26            2           80
12 2020-01-07           65           40
13 2020-05-04            9           93
14 2020-12-30           93           30
>
```

O que eu gostaria é combinar, vincular ou relacionar todos os brincos da sequência.  Montando uma tabela como esta:

```
   id_brinco_un<-c(1,1,5,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,31,31,3,4)
> id_brinco<-c(2,80,8,15,65,40,12,9,93,30,13,55,6,28)
> df2<-data.frame(id_brinco_un,id_brinco)
> df2
   id_brinco_un id_brinco
1             1         2
2             1        80
3             5         8
4            10        15
5            10        65
6            10        40
7            20        12
8            20         9
9            20        93
10           20        30
11           31        13
12           31        55
13            3         6
14            4        28
```

Desta forma eu poderia utilizar o df2 com ifelse, %in%, match, etc para tratar os dados que tiro desse banco de dados.

A tabela de reposições de brinco tem quase 2 milhões de registros. Eu tenho trabalhado com mais frequência no R utilizando tidyverse, mas qualquer solução com qualquer pacote do R é bem vinda.

Comment: Olá @ifelipec, bem vindo ao SOpt. O exemplo que postou contém apenas um animal, então é difícil sugerir uma solução que se aplique aos seus dados originais. Se possível, poste um exemplo dele, ou forneça um exemplo mais completo. Veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) como fazer isso.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta Adicionei um exemplo mais complexo e próximo da minha realidade. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Pode interpretar os dados como grafo e identificar as sequências de mudança de ID.

```
library(igraph)

grafo <- graph_from_data_frame(df[, c("id_brinco_or", "id_brinco_rp")])
```

As datas não são necessárias porque os dados são direcionados:

```
plot(grafo)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
# IDs iniciais
ids.iniciais <- with(df, id_brinco_or[!id_brinco_or %in% id_brinco_rp])

# Matriz de distâncias saindo dos IDs originais
matd <- distances(grafo, as.character(ids.iniciais), mode = "out")

# Cria uma lista com as sequências de IDs 
lids <- apply(matd, 1, function(x) colnames(matd)[x > 0 & x < Inf])

# Converte a lista para data.frame com os nomes desejados:
df2 <- setNames(stack(lids)[2:1], c("id_brinco_un", "id_brinco"))

df2
#>    id_brinco_un id_brinco
#> 1             1         2
#> 2             1        80
#> 3             5         8
#> 4            10        15
#> 5            10        65
#> 6            10        40
#> 7            20        12
#> 8            20         9
#> 9            20        93
#> 10           20        30
#> 11           31        13
#> 12           31        55
#> 13            3         6
#> 14            4        28
```

**Alternativa**

Se a matriz de distâncias fica muito grande para seus dados completos, pode tentar outra abordagem usando `clusters` para identificar os grupos (diferentes animais) e trabalhando os dados com *data.table* ou *dplyr*:

```
animal <- clusters(grafo)$membership
```

*Com data.table*

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, id_brinco_rp := as.character(id_brinco_rp)]

df2 <- merge(as.data.table(animal, "id_brinco"), df, by.x = "id_brinco", by.y = "id_brinco_rp")

df2[, id_brinco_un := id_brinco_or[date == min(date)], by = animal]
setorder(df2, id_brinco_un, date)

df2[, .(id_brinco_un, id_brinco)]
```

*Com tidyverse*

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)  # para o enframe

df <- df %>% mutate(id_brinco_rp = as.character(id_brinco_rp))

animal %>%
  enframe("id_brinco") %>%
  inner_join(df, by = c("id_brinco" = "id_brinco_rp")) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(id_brinco_un = id_brinco_or[date == min(date)]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(id_brinco_un, date) %>%
  select(id_brinco_un, id_brinco)
```

Comment: a função distances no grafo do meu caso provocou um "crash" no R. O caso é bem maior que o exemplo, são 1,7 milhões de registros, isso gerou um grafo com 10 elementos e 330 mb segundo o R. Imagino que seja grande demais para a memória que tenho disponível: 8 gb.