# Como selecionar uma coluna dos dados no R para fazer contas?

Tags: r, estatística-bootstrap

Eu tenho a tabela do estimador de kaplan-meier, e quero usar a coluna 'survival' dessa tabela para realizar as contas de outros estimadores.

[image: R]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Olá Alicia, bem vinda ao SOpt. Para ter sua pergunta respondida adequadamente, forneça um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Nunca poste código ou dados como imagem. Confira [esta postagem sobre como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r).

Answer (score 1):

Alícia, se eu entendi corretamente, você quer:

1. Calcular a estimação de Kaplan-Meier para seus dados;
2. Calcular o sumário dessa estimação através do comando `summary()`;
3. Extrair a coluna `survival` deste sumário.

Para esse caso, basta usar o operador `$` seguido do nome da coluna, como neste exemplo reduzido:

```
library(survival)

tempos <- c(7,34,42,63)

trat <- c(rep(0,4))

# estimador km

ekm <- survfit(Surv(tempos)~trat)

# Sumario
sum_ekm <- summary(ekm)

# Extraindo coluna survival

sum_ekm$surv
```

Edit: me esqueci que isso também é possível através da sintaxe de seleção de elementos de uma lista, já que sum_ekm é considerada uma no R. Daria pra utilizar também `sum_ekm[6]`.