# Como deixar o gráfico interativo em R?

Tags: r, gráfico

eu tenho o seguinte código de gráfico e preciso deixar ele interativo quando passar o mouse encima dos nomes.

```
regressao <- y ~ x
 
  grafico_biocombustiveis = ggplot(data = biocombustiveis, aes(x = Bioetanol, y = Biodiesel)) +
    geom_smooth(method="lm", se = FALSE, formula = regressao,linetype=5,colour= "#000080",)+
    stat_poly_eq(formula = regressao,
                 aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),
                 parse = TRUE, coef.digits = 4, f.digits = 5, p.digits = 10, colour = "#4169E1" )+
    geom_point(colour = "#1E90FF",size = 2)+
    geom_label_repel( label = biocombustiveis$Pais, colour = "#363636", max.overlaps = 315, box.padding = unit(0.35, 'lines'),plo)+
    scale_x_continuous(labels = percent, breaks = seq(00,.30,.05)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, breaks = seq(00,.35,.05))+
    theme_bw()+
    labs(title = "Biodiesel e etanol (% de volume mandatado aprox.)", x = "Bioetanol", y = "Biodiesel")

      grafico_biocombustiveis
```

[image: grafico]

[image: grafico interativo que o codigo cria]

Comment: Segue os dados do data frame que cria o grafico:  País Bioetanol Biodiesel
Angola 10% 0%
Argentina 12% 10%
Austrália 1,40% 0,20%
Áustria 3,40% 6,30%
Bélgica 8,50% 8,50%
Bolívia 10% 0%
Brasil 27% 12%
Canada 5% 2%
China 1,70% 0,20%
Colômbia 10% 10%
Costa Rica 8% 5%
Croácia 1% 7,49%
Chipre 7,30% 7,30%
Chéquia 4,10% 6%
Dinamarca 7,60% 7,60%
Equador 5% 5%
Estônia 10% 10%
Etiopia 10% 0%
União Europeia 5,50% 7,84%
Finlândia 20% 20%
França 8,20% 8%

Comment: Não coloque dados nos comentários, edite a questão para incluí-los no corpo da pergunta. [Veja esta postagem sobre como fazer exemplos reproduzíveis em R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar `plotly` para tornar o gráfico interativo. Pode criar um rótulo personalizado ou usar o padrão que é exibir todas as variáveis fornecidas. Eis um exemplo genérico:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

dados <- data.frame(
  ID = LETTERS,
  x = iris[1:26, 1],
  y = iris[1:26, 2])

pl <- ggplot(dados, aes(x, y, text = paste(ID, "<br>Y:", y, "<br>X:", x))) +
  geom_point()

ggplotly(pl, tooltip = "text")
```

Comment: Eu usei o plotly mas ele não mostra o texto só os pontos.

Comment: Encima eu anexei o gráfico que o código cria, mas não ficou do jeito que eu quero, eu preciso que mostre o texto dos países também (geom_text). Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Adicionou uma `geom_label` como no seu exemplo?

Comment: sim, Também não deu certo.

Comment: Use `geom_text` ou `geom_label`, com `label` na `aes` (para poder especificar texto personalizado usando `text` para os rótulos interativos. Não use `geom_*_repel`, o plotly não tem suporte para ela.