# Como consigo plotar apenas a sazonalidade da função decompose?

Tags: r

Fiz o decompose de uma série temporal através do seguinte código:

```
dados_ts2 <-  ts(dados$Contratos, start = 1, frequency = 12)
componentes <- decompose(dados_ts2, type = "mult")
plot(componentes)
```

E o resultado foi o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa maneira, quero poder plotar apenas a sazonalidade e dar zoom nela.

Alguém sabe como faz?

Comment: Acho que `plot(componentes$seasonal )` faz o que você precisa

Comment: Para ter sua pergunta respondida adequadamente, forneça um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Pode conferir esta postagem sobre [como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264168/quais-as-principais-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-se-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r).

Answer (score 2):

Veja a ajuda para `decompose`: ela retorna uma lista com os elementos separados. Como não postou uma amostra dos seus dados, vou usar de exemplo o *dataset* `AirPassengers`, incluso no R:

```
componentes <- decompose(AirPassengers, type = "mult")

str(componentes)
#> List of 6
#>  $ x       : Time-Series [1:144] from 1949 to 1961: 112 118 132 129 121 135 148 148 136 119 ...
#>  $ seasonal: Time-Series [1:144] from 1949 to 1961: 0.91 0.884 1.007 0.976 0.981 ...
#>  $ trend   : Time-Series [1:144] from 1949 to 1961: NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ random  : Time-Series [1:144] from 1949 to 1961: NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ figure  : num [1:12] 0.91 0.884 1.007 0.976 0.981 ...
#>  $ type    : chr "multiplicative"
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "decomposed.ts"
```

Para plotar apenas o componente sazonal, indique ele para `plot`. Para dar zoom, pode usar as opções `xlim` e/ou `ylim`:

```
plot(componentes$seasonal, xlim = c(1952, 1956), ylim = c(.9, 1.1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]